# UIView with rounded corners?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UIView with rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509547/uiview-with-rounded-corners)

I want to have a view with rounded corners rather then sharp. Is there some default way of doing this?

Comment: Dup (with excellent answers): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509547/uiview-with-rounded-corners

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this by manipulating the `layer` of the view and its `masksToBounds` property. I have the following code in a `UIView` category:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
...
- (void)addRoundedCornersWithRadius:(NSInteger)cornerRadiusInPixels
{
    self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadiusInPixels;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.opaque = NO;
}

- (void)makeEndsRounded
{
    CGFloat minSide = fmin(self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
    [self addRoundedCornersWithRadius:minSide/2];
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the line "self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;"?

Comment: Sublayers are also clipped. To do the above you actually only need to import `CALayer.h`, but there's no gain in importing a file instead of a framework. Rather, header files like `CALayer.h` contain comments that will help and you can look through these if you have a question.

Comment: I'll also say that in my limited experience animating a rounded layer is expensive for the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of - since `UIViews` are specified by `CGRects` they are technically always rectangular. If you want a rounded effect, you need a background image with rounded corners.

Comment: ok nvm this the other answers are better