# Where do I start to create a "Contact Info" page/table?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

I want to create a view in my app where the user can contact me. At first glance I can see it's a grouped table view, but I'm unsure about the top part?

How do I get the Logo/Thumbnail there along side the big text and small text? 
- I'm assuming it's a custom tableview cell?

Also, what about adding the buttons into a table cell? all evenly spaced apart? Would this also be through a custom table view cell? (designed in IB)

One last thing, is how would I put these two cells in with the rest?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the green image and the three buttons on top (call, email, visit website) are all subviews of the table's [header view](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/tableHeaderView). You can easily do that, if you go to Interface Builder and drag a UIView to the top part of your UITableView.
Then, you will need custom cells for the next part of the interface. One easy way is to make them all in IB and then create outlets and hook them to your table. Read the [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18) regarding more alternatives for custom cells. If you need more customization, start from [this](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) excellent article. Finally, regarding the bluish rounded background of number "20", have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509547/uiview-with-rounded-corners) SO question. Good luck!

Comment: I just had a fiddle with IB, turns out i can pretty much design the entire top with a UIView as a Header and just put a custom TableView cell in there. Thought it was gonna be a lot harder than that aha. thanks again!