# How can I make a UISearchDisplayController tableview rounded?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a UISearchDisplayController that I've added in IB. How can I make its tableview grouped with rounded corners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I can't unless I subclass it and change the tableview to the grouped type.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the exact view you want to round but you can round any `UIView` object by doing

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
yourView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
```

Now simply outlet your view in IB and you should be done.

[Original post found on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509547/uiview-with-rounded-corners).