# Reminders IOS 5 UITableView Look & Design

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, ios5

I would like to create the same UITableView look of a notepad as is in the IOS 5 Reminders application.
What is the best way to go about creating this view, note:
1. Vertical double line separator
2. Rounded Corners as is the case in UITableViewStyleGrouped but also for the group header view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is a lot of custom images that Apple (so beautifully) made such as the cool `UIPageControl` or the background(s) which you could make in photoshop, or you could take the time and learn to do some of the cool visuals with Apple's [drawing class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreRefCollection/_index.html). But as far as the rounding of the edges it's just importing `QuartzCore.h` into your project and setting the corer radius of the UIView/UITableView/UIImageView desired as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509547/uiview-with-rounded-corners).

```
view.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
```

If you are also asking about the way they have set up the general app then it's (sort of) simple in theory. It's a UIScrollView of UIViews holding UIImages for backgrounds and UITableViews for the data on that page.

[image]

Comment: thanks but i want to create a tableview with cells and a header that is rounded not a single view as it the case with reminders

Comment: You're going to have to explain in more detail what you want. I don't think i follow.

Comment: Sure - i am trying to create a table view cell header with rounded corners so each group of cells have the reminder app effect of notepad. I managed to do it with and image for the background of the cell's header

Comment: Honestly, I don't see a UITableView header that's rounded. Where is it?

Comment: I want to create an application that is in style like the reminders