# UITableView custom divider for empty cells

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I want to make sample that should use technic that you can see in Reminders, ibooks, note apps.
[image]

[image]

As you can see in Reminders app divider is looks like this:
[image]
[image]

Reminders has dot line divider.
iBook has bookshelf divider.
So the question is how to make custom divider like in example apps? And divider should be drawing even if no data set up to table view.

Comment: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

Comment: In this case it really is going to come down to custom images, and a custom UITableView

Comment: I don't think that following link will help. I find some idea but I don't how to implement it. Idea you can find in answer [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786183/reminders-ios-5-uitableview-look-design)

Comment: The divider is part of the image bases backing!!!  I have done UITableViews like this.

Comment: Could you sent me a sample code, please? And will the divider showing without data?

Comment: I have posted an answer with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add `UIView` with `backgroundColor` as `patternWithColor:["your image with custom  divider"]` below `UITableView` contentSize.

```
CGSize size = _tableView.contentSize;
UIView *footerImageView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, size.height + 50, 320.0f, 600.0f)];
footerImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Shelf.png"]];
[_tableView addSubview:footerImageView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try using section headers to give you your custom view? In the .m file, try:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView; {
  return [_cellArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section; {
  return 1;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section; {
  CustomView * customView = [[CustomView alloc] init]; // This view is the custom view you want, like the dotted lines for example.
  return customView;
}
```

As for always having it show up, you may have to add in blank cells in order to get this appearance. Hope that Helps!!!

Comment: "And divider should be drawing even if no data set up to table view." I mean the same effect when you open ibooks or reminders and their no content and dividers still be drawing.

Comment: That's what I said above. Just implement blank cells in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method as well as your normal cells, and you will draw the divider even if there is no data.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you implement the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Inside of that method you implement recognition of your top most, bottom most, and all other cells and set their bag round images appropriately.

In the case of the bookshelf looking tableview I would implement the top most with a shelf at the bottom, and a top of a bookshelf.  For all others, I would implement a standard looking middle shelf, and for the bottom most implement a more bottom looking shelf.

So to implement the what Im talking about in the cellForRoatAtIndexPath method some code like this should work

```
UIImage * rowBackground;
UIImage * selectionBackground;

if( 0 == [indexPath row] ){
    rowBackground       = [UIImage imageNamed:@"listBackingTop.png"];
    selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"listBackingTopSelected.png"];
}else if( 217 == [indexPath row] ){
    rowBackground       = [UIImage imageNamed:@"listBackingBottom.png"];
    selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"listBackingBottomSelected.png"];
}else{      
    rowBackground       = [UIImage imageNamed:@"listBackingMiddle.png"];
    selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"listBackingMiddleSelected.png"];
}

((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).image         = rowBackground;
((UIImageView *)cell.selectedBackgroundView).image = selectionBackground;
```

In my case above, 217 was my max row number.

Remember you control how many rows there are, so you can implement different backing for each row if you wanted.  Ive done tableviews where I did a blue for even and orange for odd numbered rows and still had rounded tops bottoms and square in-between looking cells.

Here is some code for an even more complex setup, the one with orange and blue and differing top and bottom cells from the middle cells.  Also with a more dynamic about of cells.

```
UIImage * rowBackground;
UIImage * selectionBackground;
UIImage * accessoryImage;
UIImage * backingImage;

if( 0 == [indexPath row] ){
    rowBackground       = [UIImage imageNamed:@"listTop.png"];
    selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"listTopDown.png"];
}else if( (amountRows - 1) == [indexPath row] ){

    if( 0 == ([indexPath row] % 2) ){
        rowBackground       = [UIImage imageNamed:@"listBottomOrange.png"];
        selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"listBottomOrangeDown.png"];
    }else{
        rowBackground       = [UIImage imageNamed:@"listBottomBlue.png"];
        selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"listBottomBlueDown.png"];
    }

}else{      
    if( 0 == ([indexPath row] % 2) ){
        rowBackground       = [UIImage imageNamed:@"listMiddleOrange.png"];
        selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"listMiddleOrangeDown.png"];
    }else{
        rowBackground       = [UIImage imageNamed:@"listMiddleBlue.png"];
        selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"listMiddleBlueDown.png"];
    }
}

accessoryImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"];
accessory.image = accessoryImage;

backingImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageBacking.png"];
imageBack.image = backingImage;

((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).image         = rowBackground;
cell.backgroundView.alpha                          = 0.9;
((UIImageView *)cell.selectedBackgroundView).image = selectionBackground;
cell.selectedBackgroundView.alpha                  = 0.5;
```

I think the major point Im trying to make is don't separate the separator from the cell just let it be part of the cell backing.