# Can't use cornerRadius button in tabelfooter

Tags: objective-c

i have a Round corner button in custom tableview footer section
am using this line code 
( addRecordButton.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0f; ) it's show "property cornerRadius can't found in forward class
please anyone can suggest me how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the QuartzCore framework before you can use that property. First, link the QuartzCore framework to your project, then:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

at the top of your file. Then you can use:

```
addRecordButton.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0f;
```

to set the corner radius.

This is a very [common problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509547/uiview-with-rounded-corners)