# How do you change the color of a UIDatePicker?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uidatepicker

If anyone has ever wanted to know how to change the background color of a UIDatePicker (the portion that goes around the actual spinner), see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the color that you want just alter the `createCover` method to set `cover` to whatever color you desire.

```
//CustomizableDatePicker.m

#import "CustomizableDatePicker.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

#define TOP_HEIGHT 9.7f
#define BOTTOM_HEIGHT TOP_HEIGHT
#define DATE_AND_TIME_MODE_ACTUAL_PICKER_WIDTH 302.5f
#define DATE_MODE_ACTUAL_PICKER_WIDTH 280.0f
#define TIME_MODE_ACTUAL_PICKER_WIDTH 176.0f

@interface CustomizableDatePicker()
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIView *myLeftCover;
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIView *myRightCover;
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIView *myTopCover;
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIView *myBottomCover;
@end

@implementation CustomizableDatePicker
@synthesize myLeftCover = _myLeftCover, myRightCover = _myRightCover, myTopCover = _myTopCover, myBottomCover = _myBottomCover;

- (void) setDatePickerMode:(UIDatePickerMode)datePickerMode
{
    [super setDatePickerMode:datePickerMode];

    [self setNeedsLayout];
}

- (void) awakeFromNib
{
    [self addCoverViews];
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    self.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [self setNeedsLayout];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (id) init
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        [self addCoverViews];
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
        self.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [self setNeedsLayout];
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }

    return self;
}

/*
 * Creates, but does NOT set the frames of, the 4 covers
 */
- (void) addCoverViews
{
    UIView *left = [self createCover];
    self.myLeftCover = left;
    [self addSubview:left];

    UIView *right = [self createCover];
    self.myRightCover = right;
    [self addSubview:right];

    UIView *top = [self createCover];
    self.myTopCover = top;
    [self addSubview:top];

    UIView *bottom = [self createCover];
    self.myBottomCover = bottom;
    [self addSubview:bottom];
}

/*
 * Helper function to create one cover
 */
- (UIView *) createCover;
{
    UIView *cover = [[UIView alloc] init];
    cover.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cover.alpha = .55;
    return cover;
}

- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    float pickerWidth;
    if(self.datePickerMode == UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime)
    {
        pickerWidth = DATE_AND_TIME_MODE_ACTUAL_PICKER_WIDTH;
    }
    else if(self.datePickerMode == UIDatePickerModeDate)
    {
        pickerWidth = DATE_MODE_ACTUAL_PICKER_WIDTH;
    }
    else if(self.datePickerMode == UIDatePickerModeTime)
    {
        pickerWidth = TIME_MODE_ACTUAL_PICKER_WIDTH;
    }
    // Set left frame
    {
        float xOrigin = 0;
        float yOrigin = TOP_HEIGHT;
        float width = (self.frame.size.width - pickerWidth) / 2;
        float height = self.frame.size.height - TOP_HEIGHT - BOTTOM_HEIGHT ;
        self.myLeftCover.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, yOrigin, width, height);
    }
    // Set top frame
    {
        float xOrigin = 0;
        float yOrigin = 0;
        float width = self.frame.size.width;
        float height = TOP_HEIGHT;
        self.myTopCover.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, yOrigin, width, height);
    }
    // Set right frame
    {
        float xOrigin = (self.frame.size.width - pickerWidth) / 2 + pickerWidth;
        float yOrigin = TOP_HEIGHT;
        float width = (self.frame.size.width - pickerWidth) / 2;
        float height = self.frame.size.height - TOP_HEIGHT - BOTTOM_HEIGHT ;
        self.myRightCover.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, yOrigin, width, height);
    }
    // Set bottom frame
    {
        float xOrigin = 0;
        float yOrigin = self.frame.size.height - BOTTOM_HEIGHT;
        float width = self.frame.size.width;
        float height = BOTTOM_HEIGHT;
        self.myBottomCover.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, yOrigin, width, height);
    }
}

@end




//CustomizableDatePicker.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

/*
 * Allows for changing the color of UIDatePickers...Pretty useful, huh? :)
 */
@interface CustomizableDatePicker : UIDatePicker

@end
```

Comment: Been searching since forever for something like this. Found an overlay class, but that slows the loading times substantially, so I would really like to use this. I'm not that great with CoreAnimation, so that's why I'm asking here ...

Is there any way the corners can be rounded? So the picker has a more natural look, like the default one? Would be awesome if you could help me out, or at least guide me on how to solve it myself; I don't avoid learning.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't really have time to give you a full explanation but this is how you can make rounded corners for a `UIView`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509547/uiview-with-rounded-corners

Comment: Sadly I didn't ask properly, it was kinda late :) The inside corners have to be rounded (inwards). The basic UIView round corners aren't really helpful. Well, thanks for taking your time to answer, if at any time in the future you free up a little bit, it would be awesome to tweak this class and bring it to looking-as-the-default-one standard. Thanks again!