# Round corners in UIView: CALayer or background Image?

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer

I need to make a UIView with rounded corners like this([image: View with rounded corners]) in tableView with a very large number of items. Therefore, my question is whether the CALayer bad influence on smooth scrolling, and may be better to use for the background image for this case?

Thanks.

Comment: duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509547/uiview-with-rounded-corners

Comment: @Farnabaz I know how to implement it using CALayer. I ask that it is better to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CALayer is fine. Transparency is bad for performance though.