# iOS draw simple bar charts like Mint app

Tags: ios, objective-c, charts

I want to create a custom cell like one in the Mint app which does pretty much the same thing. How do I go about drawing the two bars using the earned and spent data?

Thanks,

[image: custom Cell]

I got this far:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    UIColor * earningStartColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:15/255.0f green:227/255.0f blue:0/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    UIColor * earningEndColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:15/255.0f green:188/255.0f blue:0/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

    CGRect earningRect = CGRectMake(5, 32, 60, 13);

    UIBezierPath *pathE = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:earningRect
                                                     cornerRadius:3.0];
    [pathE addClip];

    drawGlossAndGradient(context, earningRect, earningStartColor.CGColor, earningEndColor.CGColor);


    UIColor * spentStartColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0f green:88/255.0f blue:67/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    UIColor * spentEndColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0f green:52/255.0f blue:49/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

    CGRect spentRect = CGRectMake(5, 52, 25, 13);    

    UIBezierPath *pathS = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:spentRect
                                                    cornerRadius:5.0];
    [pathS addClip];

    drawGlossAndGradient(context, spentRect, spentStartColor.CGColor, spentEndColor.CGColor);
}
```

However, after addClip the drawing stops so only one bar is displayed. If i wrapped addClip around  CGContextSaveGState & CGContextRestoreGState, only the second bar corners are rounded.

I also tried subclass a view and draw on the view then add as a subview to my tableviewcell and use cornerRadius, but the drawing is actually lying behind the view, so it appears as the rounded view (with its background) with the rectangle bar behind. I thought this should be easier than it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bug is because of the `[pathE addClip];`

About the `addClip` method , the apple doc said :

> Important: If you need to remove the clipping region to perform
>   subsequent drawing operations, you must save the current graphics
>   state (using the CGContextSaveGState function) before calling this
>   method. When you no longer need the clipping region, you can then
>   restore the previous drawing properties and clipping region using the
>   CGContextRestoreGState function.

so you should save the graphics state before `addClip` and restore the graphics state after `addClip`

This can help you :

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    UIColor * earningStartColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:15/255.0f green:227/255.0f blue:0/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    UIColor * earningEndColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:15/255.0f green:188/255.0f blue:0/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

    CGRect earningRect = CGRectMake(5, 32, 60, 13);

    UIBezierPath *pathE = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:earningRect
                                                     cornerRadius:3.0];
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    [pathE addClip];

    drawGlossAndGradient(context, earningRect, earningStartColor.CGColor, earningEndColor.CGColor);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    UIColor * spentStartColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0f green:88/255.0f blue:67/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    UIColor * spentEndColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0f green:52/255.0f blue:49/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

    CGRect spentRect = CGRectMake(5, 52, 25, 13);

    UIBezierPath *pathS = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:spentRect
                                                     cornerRadius:5.0];
    [pathS addClip];

    drawGlossAndGradient(context, spentRect, spentStartColor.CGColor, spentEndColor.CGColor);
}
```

PS: I think you can post your `drawGlossAndGradient` to the stackoverflow , so others can help easy , and may be helpful for others who search the answer.

And I fake the `drawGlossAndGradient` method

```
void drawGlossAndGradient(CGContextRef context, CGRect rect, CGColorRef startColor,
                          CGColorRef endColor) {
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGFloat locations[] = {0.0, 1.0};

    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(__bridge id) startColor, (__bridge id) endColor, nil];

    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace,
                                                        (__bridge CFArrayRef) colors, locations);

    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));

    CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
    CGContextClip(context);
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);

    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

}
```

The effect like this :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That's not more than a `UIView` with a gradient and round corners. [This](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32283/core-graphics-tutorial-lines-rectangles-and-gradients) is more than enough for you.

Round corners:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
...

view.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509547/uiview-with-rounded-corners).

Comment: Thanks, I'm able to draw the two bars. Not sure how to do the corner curves though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save yourself some coding, take a look at [Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/), a Mac/iOS framework for drawing and animating graphs.