# How do I create connected text fields in ios?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, authentication, xcode6

I want to create a login screen similar to facebook's for my iOS app.

[image: sample]

How do I create 2 text-fields that are both in that rounded box?

Answer (score 2):

Embed two textfields in a `UIView` and give that view the `layer.cornerRadius` that you need

[Giving UIView rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509547/uiview-with-rounded-corners)

Answer (score 0):

1. add 2 UITextfields and set their borders to none
2. add background image having rounded corner from top left and top right to the 1st uitextfield i.e. username uitextfield
3. add background image having rounded corner from bottom left and bottom right to the 2nd uitextfield i.e. password uitextfield
4. add a bordered layer (CALayer), set layer properties like, borderwidth, borderColor and frame as per your requirement and add this layer to uitextfield layer.

Comment: Instead of background images with rounded corners, just use the `cornerRadius` property of the `CALayer`.

Comment: @Arkku, cornerRadius will adjust radius of all 4 sides of the uitextfield.

Comment: That's why you put them in a third view which contains both and has the corner radius.

Comment: which is why you add corner radius to the UIView in which it has been embedded

Comment: @Rajeev, thts a nice fix up.

Comment: @ZAZ much appreciated :)