# Get corner radius value of a view

Tags: android, cornerradius

How do I retrieve the corner radius value of a view ( a cardview for example ) programmatically ? I am going to use that value in a transition animation

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509547/giving-uiview-rounded-corners) is the answer for a view.

Answer (score 0):

```
CardView cardView = (CardView)findViewById(R.id.your_id);
.
.
float radius = cardView.getRadius();
```

Comment: can't find a method called getRadius

Comment: Its a method only for CardView