# How can I create half rounded border to rounded UIImageView?

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiimageview, swift4

I have a `UIImageView`, and make it rounded. Now I want to set a green color border to that view but only for the half bottom part.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: add some code here that what you have tried then post a question here with that code so someone can help you in that.

Comment: Have you tired anything . ? provide some code please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Giving UIView rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509547/giving-uiview-rounded-corners)

Comment: spelling improved

Answer (score 0):

Hey i got what you want . 
but you could post your code here that would be best . 
btw you have rounded image and you want to the half border to be green or something . 
this can be done by 
border-bottom: 5px solid red;

you can check it how it work in code pin.

```
`https://codepen.io/Hariskhan488/pen/EoNPBv`
```

Comment: Did you notice this question was about iOS and not web development ?

Comment: Ohhh sorry I didn't ! My mistake