# Here corner is working but shadow is not work in iOS 9 and 10

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, shadow, cornerradius

> Here corner is working but shadow is not work in iOS 9 and 10
>
> and iOS 11 both are working fine

```
 viewBlueMe.chatCellDesign([.topLeft,.bottomLeft,.topRight], [.layerMinXMinYCorner,.layerMinXMaxYCorner,.layerMaxXMinYCorner], radius: 5)
```

extenstion :

```
    extension UIView {
    func chatCellDesign(_ corners:UIRectCorner,_ cormerMask:CACornerMask, radius: CGFloat) {

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *){
            self.clipsToBounds = false
            self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
            self.layer.maskedCorners = cormerMask

            self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
            self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
            self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
            self.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        }else{
            let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
            rectShape.bounds = self.frame
            rectShape.position = self.center
            rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,    byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius)).cgPath
            self.layer.mask = rectShape

            // FIXME: THIS CODE IS NOT WORK
            self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
            self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
            self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
            self.layer.shadowRadius = 5


        }
    }
}
```

i need this type of output in iOS 9 and 10 also this is iOS11

Thanks in advance 
[image]

Comment: Try self.layer.masksToBounds = true like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509547/giving-uiview-rounded-corners?rq=1

Comment: You should create one superview in that you can apply shadow and on subview you can apply corner radius so it will work

Comment: @FredericP already try this

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya yes  this is solution but here ios 11 work so i thought why i take 2 view

Comment: @Harshil I am sorry  i don't know is there any something in ios 11 ?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya ok  PPL is same answer  as u comment

Comment: @Harshil yes you it is perfect solution work everytime accept it :D

Comment: But my question is how to give corner radios and shadow both in single view

Comment: @Harshil Let me explain , Corner radius required clips to bound to be true (TRY IT ) then you only get corner radius only shadow will be clipped so it won't visible. If you apply clips to bound false then you get shadow but your subview's edge will be displayed as you are getting now. That's why we need two views however this question is duplicate and there are lot's of answer explaining the same thing

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya for corner radius clips to bound is false or true both cash corner radios apply i have check this

Comment: @Harshil you didn't mention "how to give corner radios and shadow both in single view" in your question

Comment: @Harshil Because you have only one label or textview in it. if you have full view matching size of your superview then you will get that issue

Comment: check else part of code here before comment fixme its for corner radios and below code for shadow

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya  textview? textview is not used here this is a label with multiple line inside the view 
cellContentView -> View (blue color ) - > Label

Comment: Does the shadow appear for iOS 9/10 if you comment out the layer mask? In other words, if you skip the rounded corners do you at least get a shadow? I have a small suspicion that the mask is clipping off the shadow that extends beyond the mask bounds. `clipsToBounds = NO` may help you here.

Comment: yes after comment layer mask shadow is appear

Comment: i have try to mask is off but its not worked

Answer (score 2):

Create one `outerview` and place your `UILabel` inside it, and please find below details,

```
outerView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
outerView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
outerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
outerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
outerView.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
```

**UPDATE**

See below image,

[image]

and this is `IBOutlets`

```
@IBOutlet weak var tmpView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var innerView: UIView!
```

You can do this way,

```
innerView.roundCorners([.topLeft, .topRight, .bottomLeft], radius: 5)
tmpView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
tmpView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
tmpView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
tmpView.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
```

Find UIView extension here,

```
extension UIView {
    func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

this will give you below output,

[image]

FYI. Play around **shadow** property for exact output you want.

Comment: If you look closely you will see 3 corners have radius and one is without it.

Comment: @PPL here iOS 11 its work with only single view and inside label so why its not working in iOS 9 and 10

Comment: @PPL ur solution is good but i am trying with single view and label

Comment: my question is how to give corner radios and shadow both in single view 

don't take 2 view bcoz its already working in iOS 11 so i want to use same layout for ios 11 and 9