# How to round specific corners of a View?

Tags: user-interface, rounding, swiftui, cornerradius

I know you can use `.cornerRadius()` to round all the corners of a SwiftUI view but is there a way to round only specific corners such as the top?

Comment: I ended up skipping SwiftUI because no matter what I did, the performance was terrible. In the end, I ended up using the maskedCorners property of the CALayer of my representable UIKit view.

Answer (score 823, accepted):

###### Demo (Source code is available at the end of the post)

[image: Demo Image]

#### iOS 16+ built-in modifier (Xcode 15 needed)

Clip the view using the new `UnevenRoundedRectangle`:

```
.clipShape(
    .rect(
        topLeadingRadius: 0,
        bottomLeadingRadius: 20,
        bottomTrailingRadius: 0,
        topTrailingRadius: 20
    )
)
```

> ⚠️ Note: Although it works from **iOS 16**, `.rect` needs **Xcode 15** to be available.

---

#### iOS 13+

You can use it like a normal modifier:

```
.cornerRadius(20, corners: [.topLeft, .bottomRight])
```

You need to implement a simple extension on `View` like this:

```
extension View {
    func cornerRadius(_ radius: CGFloat, corners: UIRectCorner) -> some View {
        clipShape( RoundedCorner(radius: radius, corners: corners) )
    }
}
```

And here is the struct behind this:

```
struct RoundedCorner: Shape {

    var radius: CGFloat = .infinity
    var corners: UIRectCorner = .allCorners

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        return Path(path.cgPath)
    }
}
```

<sub>You can also use the shape directly as a clipping mask.</sub>

---

##### Sample Project:

iOS 13 - [Source code on gist](https://gist.github.com/MojtabaHs/76bcd62ba62fdb6638877cf57a738574)
[image: Sample iOS 14]

---

iOS 16 - [Source code on gist](https://gist.github.com/MojtabaHs/81395bb2be673698e6531b7e56ba5c61)
[image: Sample iOS 16]

Comment: Hi @Mojtaba, I like this solution. Is the `var style: RoundedCornerStyle = .continuous` actually getting used here?

Comment: This solution is far cleaner than the accepted one.

Comment: Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58632759/5623035) for custom border @SorinLica

Comment: Do you know how this would be implemented in a SwiftUI view for macOS (not Catalyst)? Looks like `NSRect` doesn't have an equivalent corner object, and `NSBezierPath` doesn't have the `byRoundingCorners` parameter.

Comment: This is a good solution but adding additional modifiers (e.g. `.shadow`) won't work. Use @Peter Kreinz answer below if you want to be able to add additional modifiers.

Comment: It was working fine until ios14, view from the bottom is disappearing

Comment: It does not work properly anymore in iOS14, I had some layout problems with it.

Comment: @Cinn what layout problem exactly?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini I have a List to which only the 2 top corners are rounded, building for iOS14 now hides the bottom of this List. Applying cornerRadius to a container solves it but then the List rows overflow in the rounded corners.

Comment: Share me a link to a reproducible code. Maybe I can find a way. @Cinn

Comment: UIBezierPath not available on macOS.

Comment: Hi, @shanezzar, I met the same problem, please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64571117/4733603

Comment: it stopped working on simulator 14.3 (entire view is not visible, if rounder corners are applied), however it stil works good on device with 14.3....

Comment: I can't edit my previous comment , so here is another information: standard swift's function .cornerRadius() is not working properly too on simulator... view with rounded corners is also not visible, but it's content is visible.... strange behaviour.

Comment: This answer does not work if you are trying to round the corners of a `ScrollView`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64259513

Comment: It's a bug on iOS 14 that `clipShape` is not working as desired on `ScrollView`s @joshuakcockrell

Comment: This is just beautiful - love it and it works like a charm! Used it with Xcode 13.0 beta 5 (13A5212g)

Comment: Somebody give this man an award

Comment: it works quite well except for animations.  If I animate a view from one shape to another and the view has normal cornerRadius on all corners, the corner radius also animates.  With this method though there is no animation of the cornerRadius.  It just jumps to the new value.

Comment: Is there an alternative to `UIRectCorner` that can respect the layout direction (i.e. `topLeading` instead of `topLeft`) so that leading means left in LTR and right in RTL layout direction?

Comment: This answer would be substantially improved if it included the source code directly in the post as text, rather than images or links.  [Text in images cannot be copied to use it, and images cannot be read by users with screen readers](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273). Links may become invalid if the linked site changes.

Comment: @RyanM Thanks for your attention. The source code is included. The images are extra sample project for better understanding and playground and I think adding the code in the same style of the actual code block will reduce the focus of the reader

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer!Any idea why the iOS 16 solution requires Xcode 15? If it's in SwiftUI for iOS 16, I reckon it ought to work with Xcode 14, too.

Comment: @VoodooBoot it's a `@backDeployed`, You need newer module (included in Xcode 15) to make it work but it can work on older runtimes since it's just a wrapper around the old solutions ;)

Comment: I am proud of you @MojtabaHosseini

Answer (score 126):

There are two options, you can use a `View` with a `Path`, or you can create a custom `Shape`. In both cases you can use them standalone, or in a `.background(RoundedCorders(...))`

[image]

### Option 1: Using Path + GeometryReader

(more info on GeometryReader: https://swiftui-lab.com/geometryreader-to-the-rescue/)

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("Hello World!")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .padding(20)
            .background(RoundedCorners(color: .blue, tl: 0, tr: 30, bl: 30, br: 0))
    }
}
```

```swift
struct RoundedCorners: View {
    var color: Color = .blue
    var tl: CGFloat = 0.0
    var tr: CGFloat = 0.0
    var bl: CGFloat = 0.0
    var br: CGFloat = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Path { path in
                
                let w = geometry.size.width
                let h = geometry.size.height

                // Make sure we do not exceed the size of the rectangle
                let tr = min(min(self.tr, h/2), w/2)
                let tl = min(min(self.tl, h/2), w/2)
                let bl = min(min(self.bl, h/2), w/2)
                let br = min(min(self.br, h/2), w/2)
                
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: w / 2.0, y: 0))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: w - tr, y: 0))
                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: w - tr, y: tr), radius: tr, startAngle: Angle(degrees: -90), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 0), clockwise: false)
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: w, y: h - br))
                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: w - br, y: h - br), radius: br, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 0), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 90), clockwise: false)
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bl, y: h))
                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: bl, y: h - bl), radius: bl, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 90), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 180), clockwise: false)
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: tl))
                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: tl, y: tl), radius: tl, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 180), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 270), clockwise: false)
                path.closeSubpath()
            }
            .fill(self.color)
        }
    }
}
```

### Option 2: Custom Shape

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("Hello World!")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .padding(20)
            .background(RoundedCorners(tl: 0, tr: 30, bl: 30, br: 0).fill(Color.blue))
    }
}

struct RoundedCorners: Shape {
    var tl: CGFloat = 0.0
    var tr: CGFloat = 0.0
    var bl: CGFloat = 0.0
    var br: CGFloat = 0.0
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        
        let w = rect.size.width
        let h = rect.size.height
        
        // Make sure we do not exceed the size of the rectangle
        let tr = min(min(self.tr, h/2), w/2)
        let tl = min(min(self.tl, h/2), w/2)
        let bl = min(min(self.bl, h/2), w/2)
        let br = min(min(self.br, h/2), w/2)
        
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: w / 2.0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: w - tr, y: 0))
        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: w - tr, y: tr), radius: tr,
                    startAngle: Angle(degrees: -90), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 0), clockwise: false)
        
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: w, y: h - br))
        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: w - br, y: h - br), radius: br,
                    startAngle: Angle(degrees: 0), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 90), clockwise: false)
        
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bl, y: h))
        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: bl, y: h - bl), radius: bl,
                    startAngle: Angle(degrees: 90), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 180), clockwise: false)
        
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: tl))
        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: tl, y: tl), radius: tl,
                    startAngle: Angle(degrees: 180), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 270), clockwise: false)
        path.closeSubpath()

        return path
    }
}
```

Comment: If you define a custom `Shape` instead, you don't have to involve `GeometryReader`.

Comment: Just a small correction on option 2: I think the path starts at the wrong x value since it looks to cut off the top line in its left half. I changed the path start point to `path.move(to: CGPoint(x: tl, y: 0))` and that seemed to fix it.

Comment: This isn't as clean as answers below, but it's the only one that works as of iOS 14 when I want to round 3 corners. The other method ends up rounding all 4 when I want them rounded to `.infinity`

Comment: While using `UIBezierPath` works well on iOS, it does not work on macOS or other places were UIKit is not available. Manually drawing the path in pure SwiftUI works great on all Apple platforms.

Comment: A custom `Shape` is clearly the best way to accomplish this because it uses Native SwiftUI. @Trev14 It makes no sense to round a corner to `.infinity`.

Comment: @PeterSchorn SwiftUI handles rounding to infinity by doing the maximum amount of rounding for the current size, resulting in a capsule-like shape. It's nice to just say infinity and not have to calculate anything (note that SwiftUI has similar behaviors across the board for `.infinity`, like frame sizing where you want maximum expansion)

Answer (score 86):

**View Modifiers** made it easy:

```
struct CornerRadiusStyle: ViewModifier {
    var radius: CGFloat
    var corners: UIRectCorner
    
    struct CornerRadiusShape: Shape {

        var radius = CGFloat.infinity
        var corners = UIRectCorner.allCorners

        func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
            let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
            return Path(path.cgPath)
        }
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .clipShape(CornerRadiusShape(radius: radius, corners: corners))
    }
}

extension View {
    func cornerRadius(_ radius: CGFloat, corners: UIRectCorner) -> some View {
        ModifiedContent(content: self, modifier: CornerRadiusStyle(radius: radius, corners: corners))
    }
}
```

Example:

[image]

```
//left Button
.cornerRadius(6, corners: [.topLeft, .bottomLeft])

//right Button
.cornerRadius(6, corners: [.topRight, .bottomRight])
```

Comment: Do you know how this would be implemented in a SwiftUI view for macOS (not Catalyst)?
Looks like `NSRect` doesn't have an equivalent corner object, and `NSBezierPath` doesn't have the `byRoundingCorners` parameter.

Comment: Any else using this, or the above version on iOS 14? I find it clips any scrollview to the edges - same code runs fine on iOS 13 devices/simulators.

Comment: Hi, @RichardGroves, I met the exact same problem as you. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64571117/4733603

Comment: @KyleXie Thanks but I need it for cases where just 2 corners are rounded and there is no standard shape to do that, which is why I'd got to the custom path shape in the first place.

Comment: @RichardGroves, ah, I see. I currently use full rounded corners and use something else covered the bottom corners. I know it's really hacking, but I have no other way to make it work.

Comment: Why did you nest a struct within a struct?

Comment: @AnthonyGedeon: so the style belongs to the modifier

Comment: This solution works, but won't work when you need the element to have just a stroke instead of a .fill(). Since it clips the shape, it will clip the stroke.

Answer (score 65):

If you need only your top corners rounded - and in 99 of 100 cases I'm sure that's exactly what you're looking for - there a much simpler solution for the problem. Works like this:

1. Add some padding to the bottom of your view
2. Round all corners with `.cornerRadius(_:)`
3. Remove the padding by applying negative padding of the same value

```swift
struct OnlyTopRoundedCornersDemo: View {
    let radius = 12 // radius we need
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(height: 50)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
        .padding(.bottom, radius)
        .cornerRadius(radius)
        .padding(.bottom, -radius)
    }
}
```

The resulting view looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, its frame is perfectly aligned with its content (blue border). Same approach could be used to round pairs of bottom or side corners. Hope this helps!

Comment: So Clean, it works perfectly!

Comment: Best answer by far, since no new files necessary! Thanks!

Comment: I was looking to remove the optimization opportunity "A CAShapeLayer is used with a path that's a rect, a rounded-rect, or an ellipse. Instead, use an appropriately transformed plain CALayer with cornerRadius set", and this solution worked for me.

I'd just point that radius should be defined as CGFloat, otherwise Xcode throws an error.

Comment: Thanks! Very cool approach for round pairs!

Answer (score 13):

Another option (maybe better) is actually to step back to UIKIt for this.  Eg:

```swift
struct ButtonBackgroundShape: Shape {

    var cornerRadius: CGFloat
    var style: RoundedCornerStyle

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: cornerRadius, height: cornerRadius))
        return Path(path.cgPath)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Here an adaption for **macOS**:

```
// defines OptionSet, which corners to be rounded – same as UIRectCorner
struct RectCorner: OptionSet {
    
    let rawValue: Int
        
    static let topLeft = RectCorner(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    static let topRight = RectCorner(rawValue: 1 << 1)
    static let bottomRight = RectCorner(rawValue: 1 << 2)
    static let bottomLeft = RectCorner(rawValue: 1 << 3)
    
    static let allCorners: RectCorner = [.topLeft, topRight, .bottomLeft, .bottomRight]
}


// draws shape with specified rounded corners applying corner radius
struct RoundedCornersShape: Shape {
    
    var radius: CGFloat = .zero
    var corners: RectCorner = .allCorners

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()

        let p1 = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: corners.contains(.topLeft) ? rect.minY + radius  : rect.minY )
        let p2 = CGPoint(x: corners.contains(.topLeft) ? rect.minX + radius : rect.minX, y: rect.minY )

        let p3 = CGPoint(x: corners.contains(.topRight) ? rect.maxX - radius : rect.maxX, y: rect.minY )
        let p4 = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: corners.contains(.topRight) ? rect.minY + radius  : rect.minY )

        let p5 = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: corners.contains(.bottomRight) ? rect.maxY - radius : rect.maxY )
        let p6 = CGPoint(x: corners.contains(.bottomRight) ? rect.maxX - radius : rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY )

        let p7 = CGPoint(x: corners.contains(.bottomLeft) ? rect.minX + radius : rect.minX, y: rect.maxY )
        let p8 = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: corners.contains(.bottomLeft) ? rect.maxY - radius : rect.maxY )

        
        path.move(to: p1)
        path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY),
                    tangent2End: p2,
                    radius: radius)
        path.addLine(to: p3)
        path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY),
                    tangent2End: p4,
                    radius: radius)
        path.addLine(to: p5)
        path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY),
                    tangent2End: p6,
                    radius: radius)
        path.addLine(to: p7)
        path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY),
                    tangent2End: p8,
                    radius: radius)
        path.closeSubpath()

        return path
    }
}

// View extension, to be used like modifier:
// SomeView().roundedCorners(radius: 20, corners: [.topLeft, .bottomRight])
extension View {
    func roundedCorners(radius: CGFloat, corners: RectCorner) -> some View {
        clipShape( RoundedCornersShape(radius: radius, corners: corners) )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

**iOS 16+**

simply use [UnevenRoundedRectangle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/unevenroundedrectangle)

```
 VStack {
    UnevenRoundedRectangle(cornerRadii: .init(bottomTrailing: 50, topTrailing: 50))
                    .fill(.orange)
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
 }
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: How is this different from [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58606176/5623035) (section iOS 16+)?

Answer (score 5):

One more option to the top cleanest (iOS 15+):

```
.background(Color.orange, in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
.background(content: { Color.white.padding(.top, 20) })
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add to Kontiki's answer;

If you're using option 2 and want to add a stroke to the shape, be sure to add the following right before returning the path:

```
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: w/2.0, y: 0))
```

Otherwise, the stroke will be broken from the top left corner to the middle of the top side.

Answer (score 1):

[image: if you want to achieve this bubble]

Use the code in this link where the struct of type shape is RoundedCorners:Shape{ //}
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56763282/10637692

use below lines of code in this link before `path.closeSubpath()`

```
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 280, y: 20))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: w, y: 0))
path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: w, y: 70), radius: br,   //x =  move triangle to right left
startAngle: Angle(degrees: 0), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 180), clockwise: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**Current version of reaching this would be;**

```
VStack {
    Text("Top Leading & Trailing Corners")
}.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 200)
 .background(.white)
 .clipShape(
 .rect(cornerRadii: RectangleCornerRadii(topLeading: 24, topTrailing: 24)))
```