# add border left to VStack

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a `SwiftUI` View that looks like the following:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 16, height: 16)
                    Text("Speed")
                }.padding(.bottom, 10)
                
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 16, height: 16)
                    Text("Distance")
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

This looks like the following in the preview.

[image]

I want to add a border left of a black line to the `VStack` containing the `Text` and `Image`. In css I would do something like `border-left: 1px solid black`

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this in SwiftUI?

Comment: You could add a rectangle in the HStack with a width of 1 at the first position

Comment: There are some hacky ways to do this that I don't like. In this answer, they manually draw a shape and use it as a view modifier. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58632759/6191825

Comment: @DanubePM is there any non hacky ways that you do like? :-D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI - Add Border to One Edge of an Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58632188/swiftui-add-border-to-one-edge-of-an-image)

Comment: @DanubePM there's nothing hacky in the solution you linked. It is a good way to do it 9and some other good suggestions on that question as well). Another (primitive) way would be wrapping the whole view in another view. But _that_ is hacky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me I actually will code like this to get the view:

```
struct Sample: View {
   var body: some View {
       HStack {
           VStack(alignment: .leading) {
               ForEach(0..<5, id: \.self) { _ in
                   HStack {
                       Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                       Text("Speed")
                       Spacer()
                   }
                   .background(leftBorder)
               }
           }
           .padding(.leading)
       }
   }

   var leftBorder: some View {
       HStack {
           Rectangle()
               .frame(width: 1)
        
           Spacer()
       }
    }
}
```

The Result:

[image]

But I'm not sure if this is what you want or not, but if this help I'm happy.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in comment, the existing solution gives you some good options. A really *hacky way* would be like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        // This is a wrapper, mostly hidden except for left side
        ZStack {
            contentView
                .background(Color.white) // hide the rest of black frame
                .padding(.leading, 10) // width of "border"
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.black)
    }
    
    // This is your original view
    var contentView: some View {
        
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 16, height: 16)
                    Text("Speed")
                }.padding(.bottom, 10)
                
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 16, height: 16)
                    Text("Distance")
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```