# How to have text in shapes in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swift5

I want to add text (eg. Hi) in a shape (eg. Square) in SwiftUI and make them act as a single object.

It looks like there's no direct way to add text in shape in SwiftUI.

Comment: I started with the solutions below, but ended up going with the view extension in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58606176/9586164) because it provided a little more flexibility in the corners you want rounded.

Answer (score 38):

Here is what I consider to be a more comprehensive answer.  This will work as of Xcode 11.5:

```
Text(question)
    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
    .padding()
    .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
    .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.white).shadow(radius: 3))
```

Notes:

- fixedSize() will let the text wrap (since .lineLimit(nil) no longer is working).  You can omit it if you simply want one line of text with ellipsis
- multilineTextAlignment() allows you to center or align the text in any way
- padding() gives the text more space to breathe within the Rectangle()
- frame() sets the width and height of the Text() and hence, the Rectangle(), since it is the background of the Text()
- background() sets the shape of the Text()'s background.  I have added a fill color and a drop shadow here as well

The end result of this example is the text looks to appear within a cue card like shape!

Comment: I don't like this solution
we shouldn't need to set the frame height/width... it should work with hugging and let the amount o text to stretch the view when needed

Comment: The original question stated "I want to add text (eg. Hi) in a shape (eg. Square)".  You're not going to get a consistent shape unless you specify what that shape looks like, hence the use of frame() in this case.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but in my opinion, what matters is not the height and width itself but the relation between height and width of 1:1 . This was previously achieved easily with a constraint height = width


When working with different sizes/devices simultaneously this may cause some issues.

Comment: Well by that logic, if you just specify a relationship between height and width without specifying one of the aspects relative to the screen and pixel density, you will also have issues.  If you take what is written as a starting point (which answers the question), you are free to enhance it to your needs.

Answer (score 28):

Here is, IMO, most simple approach:

Generic schema

```
Text(_any_of_text_)
    .background(_any_of_Shape)
```

eg:

```
Text("Hello, World!")
    .background(Rectangle().stroke())

Text("Hello, World!")
    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4).stroke())
```

Comment: To add to this answer, you could also assign a .frame() property to the Text to specify an exact size for the Text/Rectangle

Answer (score 22):

Using Swift built-in shapes such as `Capsule()`, `RoundedRectangle()` and etc. Then, you can apply `.overlay` to the shape. The overlay take in any view such as `text`.

### Example:

```
var body: some View {
    Capsule()
        .fill(Color.blue)
        .overlay(
            Text("Hello World")
        )
}
```

### Outcome:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Create a new SwiftUI View and make use of a Z-Stack to create your goal.

```
struct YourCustomObject: View {

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.secondary)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)

            Text("Your desired text")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not necessarily work as intended.  If, say, the text is extremely long, it may bleed past the width or height of the rectangle's frame.

Comment: So how can we have a background aligned with the text no matter how much it has description in it ?

Answer (score 2):

```
Text("Hi")
 .frame(width: 40, height: 40, alignment: .center)
 .background(Color.black)
 .clipShape(Rectangle())
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using ZStack you can, but the text might spill from the rectangle so you use

`.offset()`

E.g:

```
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 11)
                    .stroke(Color("color5"), lineWidth: 1)
                    .frame(width: .infinity, height: 60)
               
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Adewale")
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        .foregroundColor(Color("color5"))
                        .offset(x: -95 )
                }
            }
```

use the `.offset()` to tweak the location of the Text view on the RoundedRectangle view.