# How can I add spacing between text and background colour in a Swift text box?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a text box in Swift with a background colour applied. However, the background covers some of the text as
[seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFgvb.png)

I want there to be some space between the text and the border of the background colour.

Here is my current code

```
Text(newData3)
    .foregroundColor(.gray)
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    .background(Color.yellow).frame(width: 400, alignment: .center)
    .cornerRadius(30)
    .padding(10)
```

I'm new to Swift so I'm not sure what to try. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You might need to embed your `Text` in another view where you'd apply the background color and the corners. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67417410/1801544 ?

Comment: try this: `Text(newData3).padding(10).....`, that is, put the `.padding(10)` before the other modifiers, specifically before the `.background(...)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach of adding the `.padding(10)` before the other modifiers, specifically before the `.background(...)`, like this:

```
Text(newData3).padding(10)
....
```