# SwiftUI Mask a rectangle inside a rounded rectangle

Tags: ios, swiftui, mask, round-rect

[image: Card]

Hello there.  I am wondering, in SwiftUI, how do you mask the contents of a rounded rectangle so that a child rectangle clips the corners.

In my example I have a white rounded rectangle and a pink rectangle on a zstack, I've tried to apply clipping, but the pink rectangle does not conform to the corners.

I've tried applying .mask to the white rectangle, but it gives different results to expectations (sometimes it doesn't show the pink rectangle).

I did find an example where you can set your own cornerRadius 
[Round Specific Corners SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56760335/round-specific-corners-swiftui)

But I was wondering if perhaps there was a way to mask the internals/body of the pink rectangle so that it conforms to the parent's rounded rectangle?

My code follows;

```
var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in

            Color.gray
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                .overlay(

                    ZStack (alignment: .topLeading) {

                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16,
                                         style: .continuous)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .shadow(radius: 10)
                             // Tried using .mask here 

                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(Color.pink)
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 150, alignment: .top)
                            .clipped()


                    }
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 450, alignment: .center)
            )

        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
```

Edit:  To clarify:

The pink rectangle should remain as a rectangle, but clip the top left and right to match the parent white rounded rectangle.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I correctly understood your goal, here is a solution - the only needed clip in right place is *after* internal content (two rectangles in this case) is constructed. So clipping with `RoundedRectangle` gives rounded corners around entire card. (As well as `shadow` most probably is needed to entire card, so placed at the end).

UPDATE: re-tested with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4

[image: demo]

```
ZStack (alignment: .topLeading) {
    Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(.white)

    Rectangle()
        .fill(Color.pink)
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 150, alignment: .top)
}
.clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16))       // << here !!
.frame(width: 300, height: 450, alignment: .center)
.shadow(radius: 10)
```

Comment: Is it possible that you only define the `16` once?  It seems a bit silly to define it twice for both clipShape and the RoundRectangle?   If not, its fine.

Comment: @zardon, magic numbers is always evil, here for is ok, in real project it's preferable to use named constants.

Answer (score 2):

@Asperi already posted a great answer, I have done this aswell with using `mask` modifier in [SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image/3269682-mask). Furthermore you only have to set `cornerRadius` once.

```
VStack(spacing: 0)
{
    ZStack(alignment: .center)
    {
       Rectangle()
       .fill(Color.red)
       .frame(width: 66, height: 20)

    }


    ZStack(alignment: .center)
    {
       Rectangle()
       .fill(Color.white)
       .frame(width: 66, height: 46)

    }
}
.mask(Rectangle()
        .cornerRadius(3.0)
        .frame(width: 66, height: 66)
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]check this out

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in

            Color.gray
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                .overlay(

                    ZStack (alignment: .topLeading) {

                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16,
                                         style: .continuous)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .shadow(radius: 10)
                        // Tried using .mask here

                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(Color.pink)
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 150, alignment: .top)
                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)) // <<<<<<


                    }
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 450, alignment: .center)
            )

        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: The pink rectangle should remain as a rectangle, but clip the top left and right to match the parent white rounded rectangle.  I'll update the question to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

I think the easier way is to apply cornerradius to ZStack

```
ZStack (alignment: .topLeading) {

    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16,
                 style: .continuous)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .shadow(radius: 10)
         // Tried using .mask here

    Rectangle()
       .fill(Color.pink)
       .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 150, alignment: .top)
        //.clipped() //<<= here
}
.frame(width: 300, height: 450, alignment: .center)
.cornerRadius(20) //<<= here
```