# SwiftUI Horizontal ScrollView item becomes invisible when scroll in iOS 14.3 but works fine in iOS 13

Tags: swiftui, ios14, swiftui-scrollview

[image]SwiftUI Horizontal ScrollView item becomes invisible when scrolled in iOS 14.3 but works fine in iOS 13

```
    GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack (alignment: .center) {
                       Color(UIColor(hexString: "#F2F2F7"))
                       .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                VStack(alignment: .center){


                  ScrollView (.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                 LazyHStack {
                     //contents
                       ForEach(0..<200)
                          { index in
                         Text(String(index))
                    }
                 }}
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)      // << here !!
                .frame(height: 100)

                }
            }}
```

Comment: Provided code working fine with Xcode 12.3 iOS 14.3. Also, LazyHStack is not available for iOS 13. So please provide the full reproducel code.

Comment: works well for me also, but needed to use: Text(String(index)) or Text("\(index)")

Comment: @Raja yeah LazyHStack not available in iOS 13 but for iOS 13 I used just HStack

Comment: @workingdog  done that still the same issue

Comment: @AdeyemiSeun please add full struct

Comment: @Raja thats the full struct

Comment: still works well for me using for example: Color(UIColor.green).
 However I get the numbers in the middle of the screen. Is this really all the code?

Answer (score 0):

the culprit was .cornerRadius(20, corners: [.topLeft, .topRight])
changed it to .cornerRadius(20) and it works fine

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64259513/swiftui-issue-on-ios-14-with-scrollview-hstack-content-being-cut-off/64571117