# Need to clipShape with a Shape that has only top left and bottom left rounded corners

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a view that I want to apply a `clipShape` modifier to a rounded rectangle that has only the top left and bottom left rounded corners.

I am using [this extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60512484/316469) to round specific corners of some views I have.

So, I would love if I could do this:

```
.clipShape(Rectangle().cornerRadius(20, [.topLeft, .topRight]))
```

But I got error saying Rectangle must be a shape...

So I suppose I have to create something like:

```
struct RectangleX: Shape { 
  func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    var radius = CGFloat.infinity
    var corners = UIRectCorner.allCorners
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect,
                            byRoundingCorners: corners,
                            cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius,
                                                height: radius))
    return Path(path.cgPath)
  }
}
```

but I am failing to see how do I pass the rect to this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round Specific Corners SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56760335/round-specific-corners-swiftui)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Problem

The `cornerRadius` modifier already uses `clipShape`.

```
extension View {
    func cornerRadius(_ radius: CGFloat, corners: UIRectCorner) -> some View {
        clipShape( RoundedCorner(radius: radius, corners: corners) )
    }
}
```

Which means that:

```
.clipShape(Rectangle().cornerRadius(20, [.topLeft, .topRight]))
```

can also be read as:

```
.clipShape(Rectangle().clipShape( RoundedCorner(radius: 20, corners: [.topLeft, .topRight]) ))
```

and you don't really need multiple `clipShape` modifiers.

#### Solution

Try the following instead (you don't need to use `clipShape` - the custom `cornerRadius` extension already calls it):

```
.cornerRadius(20, corners: [.topLeft, .topRight])
```

A more complete example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.red)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .cornerRadius(20, corners: [.topLeft, .topRight])
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `clipShape` explicitly:

```
.clipShape(RoundedCorner(radius: 20, corners: [.topLeft, .topRight]))
```