# I am learning swift UI how can i make my customize button like image and customize textfield as shown in image

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-list

As shown in image i need curve in the logo, text field over riding and button style curve, how can it be done?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Does this question helps you solving your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56760335/round-specific-corners-swiftui

Comment: Sir what tr, tl,br,bl stands for ?

Comment: sir what about the TextField? please help @jnpdx

Comment: If you post some code and say where you're getting stuck, I can try to help.

Comment: Sir i don't know how to provide source code so i am posting another question

Comment: [Link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lyzGvLYZy4Xzk4XbXwGWwVmyDn6gxM3L/view?usp=sharing) sharing my code i can't not able to authenticate phone number @jnpdx

Comment: Image("01 splash")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 212.0, height: 234.0)
                .position(x: 0, y: 0)
how i set image at top left corner ? please help @jnpdx