# Round Specific Corners of Stroke/Border SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface, swiftui, cornerradius

I am working on a SwiftUI project where I need a view to have a border with only some of the corners rounded (for instance, the top left and top right).

I added a RoundedRectangle with a stroke and was able to have all of the corners rounded. However, I need only some of the corners to be rounded and I couldn't figure out a way to do that.

This is the code I had to add a RoundedRectangle:

```
.overlay(
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
       .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1)
)
```

To make only specific corners rounded, I looked at this Stackoverflow post: [Round Specific Corners SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56760335/round-specific-corners-swiftui). However, I would have to get rid of the Rounded Rectangle (because it rounds all corners). I would have to use a normal border instead. But, with a normal border, it will cut out a piece of the border when rounding corners and trying any of the answers provided.

This is what I would ideally want it to look like (this is from an example from Bootstrap - we are rebuilding a website as an app):
[image: Picture]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative / easier way to recreate this. Add a white background to each of the rows and add a single gray background color behind them. Add spacing between the rows to let the gray background color appear like a divider between them. Then just add a rectangle overlay to the entire view, like you already had in your code!

```
struct CornerView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 1) {
            ForEach(0..<5) { index in
                Text("Item \(index)")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .frame(height: 55)
                    .background(Color.white)
            }
        }
        .background(Color.gray)
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1)
        )
        .padding()
    }
}

struct CornerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CornerView2()
    }
}
```