# SwiftUI Button action does not update my Observed Object

Tags: button, swiftui

I am creating a scorekeeper for board games.  I have created numbered buttons that are supposed to increment my score by the number on the buttons.  However, when the buttons are pressed no action occurs.  When I set up a break point I can tell the button is being called, but no action is occurring - even when I put in basic elements such as changing my player name.  Can you help me get the button to increment the "score" by the number displayed on the button.

```
struct ContentView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var theGame:Game
@ObservedObject var player1: Player
@ObservedObject var player2: Player
@ObservedObject var player3: Player
@ObservedObject var player4: Player
@State var isPlayer1Active: Bool = false
@State var isPlayer2Active: Bool = false
@State var isPlayer3Active: Bool = false
@State var isPlayer4Active: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        AdBannerView()
        HStack{
            VStack{
                Spacer()
                HStack{
                    VStack{
                        Button(action:{
                            player1.isPlayerActive = true
                            player2.isPlayerActive = false
                            player3.isPlayerActive = false
                            player4.isPlayerActive = false
                            theGame.activePlayer = player1.playerName
                        }){
                            PlayerView(player: player1)
                        }
                        Button(action:{
                            player1.isPlayerActive = false
                            player2.isPlayerActive = true
                            player3.isPlayerActive = false
                            player4.isPlayerActive = false
                            theGame.activePlayer = player2.playerName
                        }){
                            PlayerView(player: player2)
                        }
                        
                    }
                    VStack{
                        Button(action:{
                            player1.isPlayerActive = false
                            player2.isPlayerActive = false
                            player3.isPlayerActive = true
                            player4.isPlayerActive = false
                            theGame.activePlayer = player3.playerName
                            
                        }){
                                
                            PlayerView(player: player3)
                            
                        }
                        Button(action:{
                            player1.isPlayerActive = false
                            player2.isPlayerActive = false
                            player3.isPlayerActive = false
                            player4.isPlayerActive = true
                            theGame.activePlayer = player4.playerName
                            
                        }){
                            PlayerView(player: player4)
                        }
                        
                    }

                    addPointsCombinedView(player1: Player(), player2: Player(),player3: Player(), player4: Player())
                        .padding()
                        .layoutPriority(1)
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    ContentView(player1: Player(), player2: Player(),player3: Player(), player4: Player())
        .environmentObject(Game(numberOfPlayers: 4))
        .previewDevice("iPad Pro (9.7-inch)")
}
}
```

PlayerView

```
struct PlayerView: View {
@ObservedObject var player: Player
@EnvironmentObject var theGame:Game;
@State var changeName: Bool = false

var borderSize: CGFloat = 2
var body: some View {
    
    HStack{
        Text(player.playerName)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding()
        VStack{
            Text("Score")
            Text(player.formattedScore)
        }
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .padding()
        
    }
    .background(player.isPlayerActive ? Color.blue : Color.green)
    .cornerRadius(25)
    
    
    
    
    
}

}

/* Extension that allows custom corner radius for each corner.  This code was created by Mojtaba Hosseini and found on StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56760335/round-specific-corners-swiftui*/

/*    extension View {
func cornerRadius(_ radius: CGFloat, corners: UIRectCorner) -> some View {
    clipShape(playerRoundedCornerView(radius: radius, corners: corners) )
}
}*/
/*This code was created by Mojtaba Hosseini and found on StackOverflow     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56760335/round-specific-corners-swiftui*/
struct playerRoundedCornerView: Shape {

var radius: CGFloat = .infinity
var corners: UIRectCorner = .allCorners

func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii:   CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    return Path(path.cgPath)
}
}
struct PlayerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    PlayerView(player: Player())
}
}
```

AddScore Button

```
struct addScoreButton: View {
@ObservedObject var player1: Player
@ObservedObject var player2: Player
@ObservedObject var player3: Player
@ObservedObject var player4: Player
@EnvironmentObject var theGame:Game

var numberToAdd:String
var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
            player1.changePlayerName(newPlayerName: "Hello2")
        switch theGame.activePlayer{
        case player1.playerName:
            player1.addToScore(pointToAdd: addScore(numberToAdd: numberToAdd))
            
        case player2.playerName:
            player2.addToScore(pointToAdd: addScore(numberToAdd: numberToAdd))
        default:
            theGame.activePlayer = "hello world"
        }}){
    ZStack{
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.gray)
            //.frame(width: 75, height: 75, alignment: .center)
            .frame(minWidth: 70, idealWidth: 75, maxWidth: 100, minHeight: 70, idealHeight: 75, maxHeight: 100, alignment: .center)
            .padding(.bottom, 5)
            
        
        Text("\(numberToAdd)")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .bold()
            .font(.title)
            
    }

}

}

}
struct addScoreButton_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    addScoreButton(player1: Player(), player2: Player(),player3: Player(), player4: Player(),numberToAdd: "+1")
}
}

func addScore(numberToAdd:String) -> Int {
    switch numberToAdd {
    case "+1":
        return 1
    case "+2":
        return 2
    case "+3":
        return 3
    case "+4":
        return 4
    case "+5":
        return 5
    case "+6":
        return 6
    case "+12":
        return 12
    case "-1":
        return -1
    case "-2":
        return -2
    default:
        return -3
    }
}
```

Combined View of the buttons:

```
struct addPointsCombinedView: View {
@ObservedObject var player1: Player
@ObservedObject var player2: Player
@ObservedObject var player3: Player
@ObservedObject var player4: Player
@EnvironmentObject var theGame:Game
var one:String = "+1"
var two:String = "+2"
var three:String = "+3"
var four:String = "+4"
var five:String = "+5"
var six:String = "+6"
var twelve:String = "+12"
var negOne:String = "-1"
var negTwo:String = "-2"


var body: some View {
    HStack {
        VStack{
            addScoreButton(player1: player1, player2: player2,player3: player3, player4: player4, numberToAdd: one)
            addScoreButton(player1: player1, player2: player2,player3: player3, player4: player4,numberToAdd: four)
            addScoreButton(player1: player1, player2: player2,player3: player3, player4: player4,numberToAdd: twelve)
            
        }
        .padding(.trailing, 3)
        VStack{
            addScoreButton(player1: player1, player2: player2,player3: player3, player4: player4,numberToAdd: two)
            addScoreButton(player1: player1, player2: player2,player3: player3, player4: player4,numberToAdd: five)
            addScoreButton(player1: player1, player2: player2,player3: player3, player4: player4,numberToAdd: negOne)

        }
        VStack{
            addScoreButton(player1: player1, player2: player2,player3: player3, player4: player4,numberToAdd: three)
            addScoreButton(player1: player1, player2: player2,player3: player3, player4: player4,numberToAdd: six)
            addScoreButton(player1: player1, player2: player2,player3: player3, player4: player4,numberToAdd: negTwo)
        }
        .padding(.leading, 3)
    }
    
}
}

struct addPointsCombinedView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    addPointsCombinedView(player1: Player(), player2: Player(),player3: Player(), player4: Player())
}
}
```

PlayerObject:

```
class Player:ObservableObject {
@Published var playerName:String
@Published var score:[GameRound] = []
@Published var isPlayerPlayingThisGame:Bool
@Published var isPlayerActive:Bool
@Published var currentScore: Int
var formattedScore:String{
    String(currentScore)
}

//@Published let currentRound:Int
//@Published var beginningScore:Int
//@Published var endScore:Int
//@Published var pointsThisRound:[Int]


init(){
    playerName = "Player1"
    let newGame = GameRound(newRound: 1,beginningScore: 0 )
    isPlayerActive = false
    isPlayerPlayingThisGame = false
    currentScore = 0
    score.append(newGame)
    
}
func changePlayerName(newPlayerName: String){
    playerName = newPlayerName
}
/*adds the new points to the array of points made this round
and adds them to the current score */
func addToScore(pointToAdd: Int){
    //score.last?.addScore(pointsToAdd: pointToAdd)
    self.currentScore += pointToAdd
    score.last?.endScore += pointToAdd
    score.last?.pointsThisRound.append(pointToAdd)
    
}

/*starts a new round of the game*/
func newRound(){
    let newRound = GameRound(newRound:self.score.last!.currentRound+1,beginningScore: self.score.last!.endScore)
    self.score.append(newRound)
}
}
```

GameRoundObject

```
class GameRound{
let currentRound:Int
var beginningScore:Int
var endScore:Int
var pointsThisRound:[Int]
var scoreAsString:String{String(endScore)}

init(newRound:Int, beginningScore: Int){
    self.currentRound = newRound
    self.beginningScore = beginningScore
    self.endScore = newRound
    self.pointsThisRound = [0]
}

func addScore(pointsToAdd:Int){
    self.endScore += pointsToAdd
    self.pointsThisRound.append(pointsToAdd)
}

func roundAsString()->String{
    var roundNumber:String
    var round = "Round:"
    roundNumber = "\(self.currentRound)"
    round += roundNumber
    return round
}
```

}

Game Object

```
class Game:ObservableObject{
@Published var player1 = Player()
@Published var player2 = Player()
@Published var player3 = Player()
@Published var player4 = Player()
@Published var activePlayer:String
@Published var game:[Player] = []
@Published var currerntRound: Int

init(numberOfPlayers: Int){
    activePlayer = " "
    currerntRound = 1
    for i in 1...numberOfPlayers{
        switch i {
        case 1:
            game.append(player1)
            player1.isPlayerPlayingThisGame = true
        case 2:
            game.append(player2)
            player2.isPlayerPlayingThisGame = true
        case 3:
            game.append(player3)
            player3.isPlayerPlayingThisGame = true
        case 4:
            game.append(player4)
            player4.isPlayerPlayingThisGame = true
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have a line where you're creating new `Player` instances instead of referencing the already created ones.

Your line:

```
addPointsCombinedView(player1: Player(), player2: Player(),player3: Player(), player4: Player())
```

Should be:

```
addPointsCombinedView(player1: player1, player2: player2,player3: player3, player4: player4)
```

The above will solve your problem. However, on a general note, I'll also say that architecturally, I'm not sure it makes sense to store all of the players in `Game` environment variable that gets sent to every view *and* pass each player as an `@ObservableObject` parameter as well.

Comment: This worked thanks.  You are right about the Game environment object.  Frankly that was old code I need to clean up I was just trying something new.  

On another note - is there a way for me to make this answered so I can give you credit?

Comment: There is. You can click the green check mark to accept and the up arrow to mark it as helpful. Thanks!