# Xamarin iOS Round only some corners of a Button

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I need to achieve this effect on Xamarin.iOS for a Button (so just the blue button with rounded corners in the image), basically just make any corner of a button rounded, but not all of them at once. I prefer not using another nuget package like "Pancake" which I saw as an answer. Is there any platform specific customization on iOS to match the Android one?

[image]

I managed to achieve this on **ANDROID** like this:

```
public class DroidCustomButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        public DroidCustomButtonRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Forms.Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {                
                GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable();                         gradientDrawable.SetColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(AppConstants.Constants.CUSTOM_BACK_BUTTON_COLOR_NEW));

                float[] radius = new float[8];

                radius[0] = 0;   //Top Left corner
                radius[1] = 0;   //Top Left corner
                radius[2] = 46f;     //Top Right corner
                radius[3] = 46f;     //Top Right corner
                radius[4] = 46f;     //Bottom Right corner
                radius[5] = 46f;     //Bottom Right corner
                radius[6] = 0;   //Bottom Left corner
                radius[7] = 0;   //Bottom Left corner

                gradientDrawable.SetCornerRadii(radius);
                Control.SetBackground(gradientDrawable);
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I achieve same on **iOS** please?

```
public class iOSCustomButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            // ?
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try adapting [this Swift code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56760335/199364).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve will give that a try

Comment: Or try `Margin="-8, 0, 0, 0"`, if the button is at the edge of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **MaskedCorners** in your iOS class to control the display of graphics.

Here is my implementation class for your reference:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomButton),typeof(CurvedCornersButtonRenderer))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    class CurvedCornersButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            Control.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
            Control.ClipsToBounds = true;
            Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 15;
            Control.Layer.MaskedCorners = CoreAnimation.CACornerMask.MaxXMinYCorner | CoreAnimation.CACornerMask.MaxXMaxYCorner;
        }
   
    }
}
```

Comment: xu Li thank you, this is the answer

Comment: for anyone seeing this, make sure you include a "if (Control != null){}" check

Answer (score 1):

The above answer works, but if someone wants to change all corners, must include `CoreAnimation.CACornerMask.MinXMinYCorner|CoreAnimation.CACornerMask.MinXMaxYCorner` for "MaskedCorners".