# Round Specific Corners in a SwiftUI Mac App

Tags: macos, swiftui, appkit

I've been trying to figure out how to round **specific** corners of a SwiftUI `View` in a **Mac app**. All the solutions I can find ([such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56760335/round-specific-corners-swiftui)) apply only to iOS since it has `UIRectCorner`. There is no `NSRectCorner` equivalent that I can find.

Back in the day, I would round a specific corner of an `NSView` like this:

```
layer?.cornerRadius = 5
layer?.maskedCorners = .layerMinXMinYCorner //Bottom-left corner
```

Has anyone found a way to round specific corners in a Mac app in SwiftUI?

Comment: You can draw your custom `Shape` and use that as background or clip shape

Answer (score 11, accepted):

and here comes the answer for **macOS** :)

```
// defines OptionSet, which corners to be rounded – same as UIRectCorner
struct RectCorner: OptionSet {
    
    let rawValue: Int
        
    static let topLeft = RectCorner(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    static let topRight = RectCorner(rawValue: 1 << 1)
    static let bottomRight = RectCorner(rawValue: 1 << 2)
    static let bottomLeft = RectCorner(rawValue: 1 << 3)
    
    static let allCorners: RectCorner = [.topLeft, topRight, .bottomLeft, .bottomRight]
}


// draws shape with specified rounded corners applying corner radius
struct RoundedCornersShape: Shape {
    
    var radius: CGFloat = .zero
    var corners: RectCorner = .allCorners

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()

        let p1 = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: corners.contains(.topLeft) ? rect.minY + radius  : rect.minY )
        let p2 = CGPoint(x: corners.contains(.topLeft) ? rect.minX + radius : rect.minX, y: rect.minY )

        let p3 = CGPoint(x: corners.contains(.topRight) ? rect.maxX - radius : rect.maxX, y: rect.minY )
        let p4 = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: corners.contains(.topRight) ? rect.minY + radius  : rect.minY )

        let p5 = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: corners.contains(.bottomRight) ? rect.maxY - radius : rect.maxY )
        let p6 = CGPoint(x: corners.contains(.bottomRight) ? rect.maxX - radius : rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY )

        let p7 = CGPoint(x: corners.contains(.bottomLeft) ? rect.minX + radius : rect.minX, y: rect.maxY )
        let p8 = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: corners.contains(.bottomLeft) ? rect.maxY - radius : rect.maxY )

        
        path.move(to: p1)
        path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY),
                    tangent2End: p2,
                    radius: radius)
        path.addLine(to: p3)
        path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY),
                    tangent2End: p4,
                    radius: radius)
        path.addLine(to: p5)
        path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY),
                    tangent2End: p6,
                    radius: radius)
        path.addLine(to: p7)
        path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY),
                    tangent2End: p8,
                    radius: radius)
        path.closeSubpath()

        return path
    }
}

// View extension, to be used like modifier:
// SomeView().roundedCorners(radius: 20, corners: [.topLeft, .bottomRight])
extension View {
    func roundedCorners(radius: CGFloat, corners: RectCorner) -> some View {
        clipShape( RoundedCornersShape(radius: radius, corners: corners) )
    }
}
```

Comment: When you want to use it without using a modifier - VStack {
   Text("RoundedCornersShape")
   RoundedCornersShape(radius: 20, corners: [.topLeft, .bottomRight])
    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
   Text("RoundedCornersShape")
  }

Answer (score 1):

[image: Preview Image]

Create a custom shape

```
import SwiftUI

struct RoundCorner: Shape {
    
    // MARK: - PROPERTIES
    
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat
    var maskedCorners: UIRectCorner
    
    
    // MARK: - PATH
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: maskedCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: cornerRadius, height: cornerRadius))
        return Path(path.cgPath)
    }
}

// MARK: - PREVIEW

struct RoundCorner_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RoundCorner(cornerRadius: 20, maskedCorners: .allCorners)
    }
}
```

And Apply this shape to your view

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    
    // MARK: - BODY
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .padding()
            .background(
                Color.orange
            )
            .clipShape(
                RoundCorner(
                    cornerRadius: 12,
                    maskedCorners: [.topLeft, .bottomRight]
                )//OUR CUSTOM SHAPE
            )
    }
}

// MARK: - PREVIEW

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this will not work on **macOS** as indicated in my question. 

Comment: will not work on macOS. Please check the accepted answer. Best

Comment: your using UIBezierPath; UIBezierPath is not avalable in MacOS