# Code compiles fine, but not as XCode Swift Package; gives macos version error

Tags: swift, xcode, package

I use the following code https://stackoverflow.com/a/71249003/7997299 ( thanks ChrisR ) in my code and compiles fine under macos 13.4  Ventura.

```
// defines OptionSet, which corners to be rounded – same as UIRectCorner
struct RectCorner: OptionSet {

let rawValue: Int
    
static let topLeft = RectCorner(rawValue: 1 << 0)
static let topRight = RectCorner(rawValue: 1 << 1)
static let bottomRight = RectCorner(rawValue: 1 << 2)
static let bottomLeft = RectCorner(rawValue: 1 << 3)

static let allCorners: RectCorner = [.topLeft, topRight, .bottomLeft, .bottomRight]
}


// draws shape with specified rounded corners applying corner radius
struct RoundedCornersShape: Shape {

var radius: CGFloat = .zero
var corners: RectCorner = .allCorners

func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    var path = Path()

    let p1 = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: corners.contains(.topLeft) ? rect.minY + radius  : rect.minY )
    let p2 = CGPoint(x: corners.contains(.topLeft) ? rect.minX + radius : rect.minX, y: rect.minY )

    let p3 = CGPoint(x: corners.contains(.topRight) ? rect.maxX - radius : rect.maxX, y: rect.minY )
    let p4 = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: corners.contains(.topRight) ? rect.minY + radius  : rect.minY )

    let p5 = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: corners.contains(.bottomRight) ? rect.maxY - radius : rect.maxY )
    let p6 = CGPoint(x: corners.contains(.bottomRight) ? rect.maxX - radius : rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY )

    let p7 = CGPoint(x: corners.contains(.bottomLeft) ? rect.minX + radius : rect.minX, y: rect.maxY )
    let p8 = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: corners.contains(.bottomLeft) ? rect.maxY - radius : rect.maxY )

    
    path.move(to: p1)
    path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY),
                tangent2End: p2,
                radius: radius)
    path.addLine(to: p3)
    path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY),
                tangent2End: p4,
                radius: radius)
    path.addLine(to: p5)
    path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY),
                tangent2End: p6,
                radius: radius)
    path.addLine(to: p7)
    path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY),
                tangent2End: p8,
                radius: radius)
    path.closeSubpath()

    return path
  }
}


extension View {
  func roundedCorners(radius: CGFloat, corners: RectCorner) -> some View {
      clipShape( RoundedCornersShape(radius: radius, corners: corners) )
  }
}
```

So I decided to create a package to play with. Playing with it to learn more about packages, I come across a lot of errors when I create a packages with it. This is happening with more then one package and do avoid them for now.

I  did use this package description; adding the platforms.

```
// swift-tools-version: 5.8  <<<< was originaly 5.9 but tresult is the same
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyLibrary",
    platforms: [
            .macOS(.v10_13)
        ],
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, making them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "MyLibrary",
            targets: ["MyLibrary"]),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package, defining a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package and products from dependencies.
        .target(
            name: "MyLibrary"),
        .testTarget(
            name: "MyLibraryTests",
            dependencies: ["MyLibrary"]),
    ]
)
```

I do get 15 errors like “'Path' is only available in macOS 10.15 or newer”, but when not using as a package it compiles fine.

How is this possible? And How can I solve this.

I use XCode 15 beta 7 and XCode 14.3.1.
Get the message that the tool version is wrong, if I change the tool version to 5.8 same issue.
I did/do delete many time the derived data folder.

Added a requested image:
[image]

*I need to make the struct with **optionSet public and add a public init** into the struct, but dont get it rigth: Some suggestions?*

```
// defines OptionSet, which corners to be rounded – same as UIRectCorner
public struct RectCorner: OptionSet, Sendable {
    public init(rawValue: Int) {
        self.rawValue = RectCorner.allCorners.rawValue
    }
    public let rawValue: Int

    static let topLeft = RectCorner(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    static let topRight = RectCorner(rawValue: 1 << 1)
    static let bottomRight = RectCorner(rawValue: 1 << 2)
    static let bottomLeft = RectCorner(rawValue: 1 << 3)

    static let allCorners: RectCorner = [.topLeft, topRight, .bottomLeft, .bottomRight]
}
```

Comment: Your Package.swift says `.macOS(.v10_13)`. I don't understand why you find the error surprising. How about saying `.macOS(.v10_15)` instead?

Comment: Because it compiles and works under 10_13 and 10_14 just fine.

Comment: You just said it doesn't. You said it produces the error "'Path' is only available in macOS 10.15 or newer". It cannot compile on macOS 10.13. Can you show the steps you took to make it work under 10.13? Start with "create a new project..."

Comment: If I use the code in the app it compiles and works fine. If I create a package from it it doesn't compile and give error's. About starting a project; when starting a project I select macos and 10.13 as target. I can run this on Ventura and it works fine.

Comment: How did you “select macos and 10.13 as target”? Can you show a screenshot of that? I know there are two easily confused settings.

Comment: @Sweeper - picture added

Comment: Your screenshot clearly says *13.4*, not 10.13.

Comment: Hi thank you. That was the issue for so far; the package isn't reconized yet but thats another question. Also I need to implement a init in the optionSet. I did add that to the question, but don't get it right.

Answer (score 0):

From the Xcode project screenshot attached, it seems you are building targeting macOS 13.4 and above, which is why your Xcode project builds without any error.

In Swift package you are targeting macOS 10.13 and above and getting error since some of the APIs are not available in older macOS versions. You can do following things to resolve the issue:

1. Update target macOS version to the version your APIs are available.
2. Guard your API usage with availability conditions and provide alternate implementations for lower versions.

Comment: Thank you for your comment; but in the last answer I wrote that issue was solved. The only issue is that I can’t get the RectCornet option right for the package.