# Swiftui put border with different radii and stroke the border

Tags: swiftui, border, cornerradius

I need to put a .cornerRadius with different radii for each corner around a view with padding and I need to put an outline around that border.  Any ideas?

Comment: For setting different radii for each corner, see [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58606176/14063245)

Answer (score 0):

```
Text("one possibility")
   .font(.title)
   .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
   .padding(10)
   .border(Color.black, width: 2)
   .cornerRadius(10, 20, 30, 40)
```

Comment: This ought to work but the corner radius interferes with the border.

Comment: I gave up and drew it with a Path