# UIView frame, bounds and center

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, frame, bounds

I would like to know how to use these properties in the right manner.

As I understand, `frame` can be used from the container of the view I am creating.
It sets the view position relative to the container view. It also sets the size of that view.

Also `center` can be used from the container of the view I'm creating. This property changes the position of the view relative to its container.

Finally, `bounds` is relative to the view itself. It changes the drawable area for the view.

*Can you give more info about the relationship between `frame` and `bounds`? What about the `clipsToBounds` and `masksToBounds` properties?*

Comment: This Discussion already solved here. so pls look it here or could see developer Documentation given here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210047/iphone-development-whats-the-difference-between-the-frame-and-the-bounds http://www.slideshare.net/onoaonoa/cs193p-lecture-5-view-animation

Answer (score 588, accepted):

Since the question I asked has been seen many times I will provide a detailed answer of it. Feel free to modify it if you want to add more correct content.

First a recap on the question: frame, bounds and center and theirs relationships.

**Frame** A view's `frame` (`CGRect`) is the position of its rectangle in the `superview`'s coordinate system. By default it starts at the top left.

**Bounds** A view's `bounds` (`CGRect`) expresses a view rectangle in its own coordinate system.

**Center** A `center` is a `CGPoint` expressed in terms of the `superview`'s coordinate system and it determines the position of the exact center point of the view.

Taken from **[UIView + position](http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=24)** these are the relationships (they don't work in code since they are informal equations) among the previous properties:

- `frame.origin = center - (bounds.size / 2.0)`
- `center = frame.origin + (bounds.size / 2.0)`
- `frame.size = bounds.size`

**NOTE:** These relationships do not apply if views are rotated. For further info, I will suggest you take a look at the following image taken from **[The Kitchen Drawer](http://littlehales.wordpress.com/)** based on **[Stanford CS193p](http://cs193p.stanford.edu)** course. Credits goes to **@Rhubarb**.

[image: Frame, bounds and center]

Using the `frame` allows you to reposition and/or resize a view within its `superview`. Usually can be used from a `superview`, for example, when you create a specific subview. For example:

```
// view1 will be positioned at x = 30, y = 20 starting the top left corner of [self view]
// [self view] could be the view managed by a UIViewController
UIView* view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30.0f, 20.0f, 400.0f, 400.0f)];    
view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[[self view] addSubview:view1];
```

When you need the coordinates to drawing inside a `view` you usually refer to `bounds`. A typical example could be to draw within a `view` a subview as an inset of the first. Drawing the subview requires to know the `bounds` of the superview. For example:

```
UIView* view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0f, 50.0f, 400.0f, 400.0f)];    
view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

UIView* view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(view1.bounds, 20.0f, 20.0f)];    
view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

[view1 addSubview:view2];
```

Different behaviours happen when you change the `bounds` of a view.
For example, if you change the `bounds` `size`, the `frame` changes (and vice versa). The change happens around the `center` of the view. Use the code below and see what happens:

```
NSLog(@"Old Frame %@", NSStringFromCGRect(view2.frame));
NSLog(@"Old Center %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(view2.center));    

CGRect frame = view2.bounds;
frame.size.height += 20.0f;
frame.size.width += 20.0f;
view2.bounds = frame;

NSLog(@"New Frame %@", NSStringFromCGRect(view2.frame));
NSLog(@"New Center %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(view2.center));
```

Furthermore, if you change `bounds` `origin` you change the `origin` of its internal coordinate system. By default the `origin` is at `(0.0, 0.0)` (top left corner). For example, if you change the `origin` for `view1` you can see (comment the previous code if you want) that now the top left corner for `view2` touches the `view1` one. The motivation is quite simple. You say to `view1` that its top left corner now is at the position `(20.0, 20.0)` but since `view2`'s `frame` `origin` starts from `(20.0, 20.0)`, they will coincide.

```
CGRect frame = view1.bounds;
frame.origin.x += 20.0f;
frame.origin.y += 20.0f;
view1.bounds = frame;
```

The `origin` represents the `view`'s position within its `superview` but describes the position of the `bounds` center.

Finally, `bounds` and `origin` are not related concepts. Both allow to derive the `frame` of a view (See previous equations).

*View1's case study*

Here is what happens when using the following snippet.

```
UIView* view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30.0f, 20.0f, 400.0f, 400.0f)];
view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[[self view] addSubview:view1];

NSLog(@"view1's frame is: %@", NSStringFromCGRect([view1 frame]));
NSLog(@"view1's bounds is: %@", NSStringFromCGRect([view1 bounds]));
NSLog(@"view1's center is: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint([view1 center]));
```

The relative image.

[image]

This instead what happens if I change `[self view]` bounds like the following.

```
// previous code here...
CGRect rect = [[self view] bounds];
rect.origin.x += 30.0f;
rect.origin.y += 20.0f;
[[self view] setBounds:rect];
```

The relative image.

[image]

Here you say to `[self view]` that its top left corner now is at the position (30.0, 20.0) but since `view1`'s frame origin starts from (30.0, 20.0), they will coincide.

**Additional references** (to update with other references if you want)

- [UIView Geometry](http://littlehales.wordpress.com/2012/01/24/uiview-geometry/)
- [UIView Frames and Bounds](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2010/05/27/uiview-frames-and-bounds/)

About `clipsToBounds` (source Apple doc)

> Setting this value to YES causes subviews to be clipped to the bounds
>   of the receiver. If set to NO, subviews whose frames extend beyond the
>   visible bounds of the receiver are not clipped. The default value is
>   NO.

In other words, if a view's `frame` is `(0, 0, 100, 100)` and its subview is `(90, 90, 30, 30)`, you will see only a part of that subview. The latter won't exceed the bounds of the parent view.

`masksToBounds` is equivalent to `clipsToBounds`. Instead to a `UIView`, this property is applied to a `CALayer`. Under the hood, `clipsToBounds` calls `masksToBounds`. For further references take a look to [How is the relation between UIView's clipsToBounds and CALayer's masksToBounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177775/how-is-the-relation-between-uiviews-clipstobounds-and-calayers-maskstobounds).

Comment: @Rhubarb You are perfectly right. I will point it out in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if I will get an answer but why does the subview move in the negative direction when the bounds origins are changed. Just can't seem to get my head around that bit. Thanks!!

Comment: @nimgrg It seems that the view moves in the negative direction but it's not. Internal coordinates of the superview are changed.

Comment: forgive my geometric abilities, if the internal coordinates of the superview are changed to origin (30.0, 20.0), does the point (0,0) lie inside of the blue square or outside of it. I am just trying to track down the changes and make sense of it. Thanks for taking time to answer.

Comment: @flexaddicted: Hi, the slide you added says: "View B's middle in its own coordinate space is: bounds.size.width/2+origin.x" -- why is this the case? Since the title says in **its own** coordinate space, I would say it is: bounds.size.width/2+bounds.origin.x?? Isn't it??

Comment: @user2568508 Yes, in fact it is. ;)

Comment: @flexaddicted: hm got a bit confused now, it seems the slide says bounds.size.width/2+bounds.origin.x -- for some reasons it seems I didn't notice the `bounds` in front of origin.x and hence my comment. Seems the correct answer is: ..+bounds.origin.x

Comment: Developers mostly constrain views using either 1) storyboards (fine) 2) constraints (fine) 3) superview's frame (not fine) 4) I rarely see them use the superview's bounds. So just to conclude you're saying using superview's frame doesn't make sense, because the view may get rotated and instead the superview's bounds is the right approach. That makes sense but I guess since most of the time we're not dealing with views that are rotated we don't rune into unexpected issues. Right? **Q:** Is there anytime that actually using the superview's bounds would not be what you want? If so when?

Answer (score 140):

This question already has a good answer, but I want to supplement it with some more pictures. [My full answer is here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28917673/3681880)

To help me remember **frame**, I think of **a picture frame on a wall**. Just like a picture can be moved anywhere on the wall, the coordinate system of a view's frame is the superview. (wall=superview, frame=view)

To help me remember **bounds**, I think of **the bounds of a basketball court**. The basketball is somewhere within the court just like the coordinate system of the view's bounds is within the view itself. (court=view, basketball/players=content inside the view)

Like the frame, **view.center** is also in the coordinates of the superview.

### Frame vs Bounds - Example 1

The yellow rectangle represents the view's frame. The green rectangle represents the view's bounds. The red dot in both images represents the origin of the frame or bounds within their coordinate systems.

```
Frame
    origin = (0, 0)
    width = 80
    height = 130

Bounds 
    origin = (0, 0)
    width = 80
    height = 130
```

[image]

---

### Example 2

```
Frame
    origin = (40, 60)  // That is, x=40 and y=60
    width = 80
    height = 130

Bounds 
    origin = (0, 0)
    width = 80
    height = 130
```

[image]

---

### Example 3

```
Frame
    origin = (20, 52)  // These are just rough estimates.
    width = 118
    height = 187

Bounds 
    origin = (0, 0)
    width = 80
    height = 130
```

[image]

---

### Example 4

This is the same as example 2, except this time the whole content of the view is shown as it would look like if it weren't clipped to the bounds of the view.

```
Frame
    origin = (40, 60)
    width = 80
    height = 130

Bounds 
    origin = (0, 0)
    width = 80
    height = 130
```

[image]

---

### Example 5

```
Frame
    origin = (40, 60)
    width = 80
    height = 130

Bounds 
    origin = (280, 70)
    width = 80
    height = 130
```

[image]

Again, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28917673/3681880) for my answer with more details.

Comment: Thanks Suragch. It is really very clear picture of frame and bound difference. I really appreciate your effort.

Comment: All the stuff that I want to see in one short and concise answer. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! For Example 3: I don't get it. you only moved your frame's origin a little bit, how does that change your image's rotation?

Comment: @asma22, In example 3 I was just trying to show that when you rotate an image the frame changes but the bounds don't. [See my fuller answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28917673/3681880).

Answer (score 89):

I found this image most helpful for understanding frame, bounds, etc.

[image]

Also please note that `frame.size != bounds.size` when the image is rotated.

Comment: A picture worth thousand words.

Comment: The best possible explanation

Comment: @Erben Mo: Hi, the slide you added says: "View B's middle in its own coordinate space is: bounds.size.width/2+origin.x" -- why is this the case? Since the title says in **its own** coordinate space, I would say it is: bounds.size.width/2+bounds.origin.x?? Isn't it??

Comment: What is the source of this image? Link?

Comment: @David It's from Stanford's CS193p course on iTunesU found here: www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2013-fall

Answer (score 5):

I think if you think it from the point of `CALayer`, everything is more clear.

**Frame is not really a distinct property of the view or layer at all, it is a virtual property, computed from the bounds, position(`UIView`'s center), and transform.**

So basically how the layer/view layouts is really decided by these three property(and anchorPoint), and either of these three property won't change any other property, like changing transform doesn't change bounds.

Answer (score 3):

There are very good answers with detailed explanation to this post. I just would like to refer that there is another explanation with visual representation for the meaning of Frame, Bounds, Center, Transform, Bounds Origin in WWDC 2011 video **[Understanding UIKit Rendering](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011-121/)** starting from @4:22 till 20:10

Answer (score 0):

After reading the above answers, here adding my interpretations.

Suppose browsing online, **web browser** is your `frame` which decides where and how big to show webpage. **Scroller** of browser is your `bounds.origin` that decides which part of webpage will be shown. `bounds.origin` is hard to understand. The best way to learn is creating Single View Application, trying modify these parameters and see how subviews change.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f, 400.0f)];
[view1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(view1.bounds, 20.0f, 20.0f)];
[view2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[view1 addSubview:view2];

[[self view] addSubview:view1];

NSLog(@"Old view1 frame %@, bounds %@, center %@", NSStringFromCGRect(view1.frame), NSStringFromCGRect(view1.bounds), NSStringFromCGPoint(view1.center));
NSLog(@"Old view2 frame %@, bounds %@, center %@", NSStringFromCGRect(view2.frame), NSStringFromCGRect(view2.bounds), NSStringFromCGPoint(view2.center));

// Modify this part.
CGRect bounds = view1.bounds;
bounds.origin.x += 10.0f;
bounds.origin.y += 10.0f;

// incase you need width, height
//bounds.size.height += 20.0f;
//bounds.size.width += 20.0f;

view1.bounds = bounds;

NSLog(@"New view1 frame %@, bounds %@, center %@", NSStringFromCGRect(view1.frame), NSStringFromCGRect(view1.bounds), NSStringFromCGPoint(view1.center));
NSLog(@"New view2 frame %@, bounds %@, center %@", NSStringFromCGRect(view2.frame), NSStringFromCGRect(view2.bounds), NSStringFromCGPoint(view2.center));
```