# On iOS, can changing a UIView object's frame and center alter its internal coordinate system?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, frame, bounds

On iOS, if we change a view's `frame`, we change its `bounds`, and if we change its `bounds`, we change its `frame`.

But we can change the internal coordinate system of a view by:

```
CGRect b = v.bounds;    // v is the UIView object
b.origin.x = 10000;
b.origin.y = 10000;
v.bounds = b;
```

and now, the top left point of the view is a coordinate of `(10000, 10000)`.  Is this also possible by merely changing `frame` and `center` but not `bounds`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> On iOS, if we change a view's frame, we change its bounds, and if we change its bounds, we change its frame.

That's half true. Only the *sizes* of those two rects are bound together. From the docs:

> The size portion of the frame and bounds rectangles are coupled together so that changing the size of either rectangle updates the size of both.

That doesn't mention the origins. So your example will modify the internal coordinate system's origin without changing its position in the superview's coordinate system. You can't achieve that behavior via the `frame` or `center` properties; they only affect the the view's position in its superview's coordinate system.

Comment: To reiterate explicitly, they are _bound_, not _equal_.  Rotations will cause interesting issues. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361369/ios-programming-frame-bounds-and-center