# Cocoa: Why assigning a frame to a frame doesn´t work but assigning bounds does

Tags: cocoa-touch

I´ve been reading the different questions ( [Cocoa: What's the difference between the frame and the bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210047/cocoa-whats-the-difference-between-the-frame-and-the-bounds), [UIView frame, bounds and center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361369/ios-programming-frame-bounds-and-center)) related to the difference between frame and bounds but still I don´t understand why when something like this:

```
UILabel *newMark = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
newMark.text = @"|A3";
[self addSubview:newMark];
```

or this:

```
UILabel *newMark = [[UILabel alloc] init];
newMark.text = @"|A3";
newMark.frame = self.frame;
[self addSubview:newMark];
```

The label is not displayed, but when doing the equivalent with the bounds, like this:

```
UILabel *newMark = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
newMark.text = @"|A3";
[self addSubview:newMark];
```

or this

```
UILabel *newMark = [[UILabel alloc] init];
newMark.text = @"|A3";
newMark.frame = self.bounds;
[self addSubview:newMark];
```

it is displayed. I wouldn´t have a problem with using the bounds, but I think is not placing the label on the right place, as it can be seen on the following screenshot:

[image: Label]

Where, as you can see "|", "A" and "3" are cut because they are displayed more at the bottom than the screen of the ipad. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The `frame` is relative to its superview. So if your frame's origin is at (100,200) within your superview, and you set a subview's frame to be the same as your frame, then your subview will be at (100,200) within you.

Typically (provided there aren't transforms involved), when you want to tell a subview to be the same size as the superview, you say:

```
subview.frame = superview.bounds;
```