# Add subview programmatically and make it stretching so if it is was added through XCode

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I need to place one custom view inside the other one and make it stretched across the entire width of the parent view. Is that possible to make it programmatically? (instead of tracking the width of the parent view and updating it's rectangle). Or is it possible to add my custom view to the list of custom objects of XCode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a child view that fills the parent view even when resizing (rotating)?

```
var childView = new UIView(parentView.Bounds) 
{ 
    AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleDimensions
};
parentView.Add(childView);
```

I recommend reading up on Frame, Bounds and Center. This is a nice overview:
[UIView frame, bounds and center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361369/ios-programming-frame-bounds-and-center)

And the Apple documentation: [Adjusting the Size and Position of Views at Runtime](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html).