# Change background of frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, frame

I have a "frame within a frame" scenario.  There is a 600x600 area inside of the main screen.  What I would like to do is to just color the 600x600 area so that I can visualize where I am working.  I have tried using `self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];` but that colors the whole screen instead of just the 600x600 area.

What would be the best way to color the background of the 600x600 area?

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame: CGRectMake(84, 0, 600, 600)];
    if (self) {
        //initialization code
        tileArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity: 9];

        tile1 = [[TileView alloc]
                 initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 128, 128)
                 withImageNamed:@"Yellow1.png"];

        [self addSubview:tile1];

        int x = [self frame].size.width;
        int y = [self frame].size.width;
        NSLog(@" Width: %i. Height: %i.", x,y);
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: What about setting `self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];`? Does the color cover the entire screen?

Comment: Sorry, I should have used a better example.  When I change it to `self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];` the whole background is red instead.

Comment: SO, is this the same behavior of the previous example?

Comment: Yeah.  I'm very new to Objective-C, but would self refer to the "new" self referring to the 600x600 area?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand what you mean.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correct, self should now refer to the new 600x600 frame, correct? `self = [super initWithFrame: CGRectMake(84, 0, 600, 600)];`

Comment: Sure, `self` is the same as `this` (like in C#). It refers to the current instance.

Comment: I really suggest to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361369/ios-programming-frame-bounds-and-center/11282765#11282765. This is my answer to understand views. Hope that helps.