# Changing UIButton background image on event

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiswitch

When a `UISwitch` changes from 'OFF' to 'ON', I want the background image of a `UIButton` to change. I have the following code:

```
- (IBAction)switchValueChanged {
    if (Hard1ON.on) {
        UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red.jpg"];
        [Hard1 setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.view addSubview:Hard1];
        NSLog(@"Change");
    }
    else {
        UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"white.jpg"];
        [Hard1 setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.view addSubview:Hard1];
    }
}
```

When I hit the switch, the console logs correctly so I know that's working, however the background of the button doesn't change.

For reference, `Hard1ON` is my `UISwitch` and `Hard1` is my `UIButton`.

Comment: I added an edit for you. Hope it helps.

Comment: @flexaddicted thanks so much, one more question, how do I move this button to a different place on the screen?

Comment: You need to play with `[self.hardButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50)];` where `CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);`. Hope that helps. See also my answer on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361369/ios-programming-frame-bounds-and-center/11282765#11282765

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add your button once, the most common way is to add it in `viewDidLoad` and then change its image when you perform the switching.

So, inside `viewDidLoad` method

```
// create the button
[self.view addSubview:Hard1];
```

then, in your value changed method

```
if (Hard1ON.on) {
    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red.jpg"];
    [Hard1 setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSLog(@"Change");
} else {
    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"white.jpg"];
    [Hard1 setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

**NOTE** *use camelCase notation for naming variables*.

For example, `Hard1` should look like `hard1`. It would be better to name it as `hard1Button` or similar. The same applies for the switch element. Like for example, `hard1OnSwicth`.

**Edit**

I would try to create the button programmatically in `viewDidLoad` method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.hardButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.hardButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50)]; // set the x,y,width and height based on your specs
    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"white.jpg"];
    [self.hardButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:self.hardButton];
}
```

where hardButton is a reference to your button declared in .h (for example) like

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIButton* hardButton;
```

Synthesize it also (if you want, if not Xcode will take care for you) like this

```
@synthesize hardButton = _hardButton;
```

If you use **strong** or **retain** instead of assign and you don't use ARC release in `dealloc` like

```
- (void)dealloc
{ 
   [_hardButton release];
   [super dealloc];
}
```

Now, in your switch value changed.

```
- (IBAction)switchValueChanged
{
    UIImage* buttonImage = nil;
    if (Hard1ON.on) {
        buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red.jpg"];
    } else {
        buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"white.jpg"];
    }

    [self.hardButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, however when I try to run the program after making that change, [this](http://gyazo.com/0b8c617581450689654ff7a14456752b.png?1361707862) appears.

And about the camelCase notation - I usually do that, however the look of hard1 is just displeasing to me haha. hardOne, for instance, looks ok to me. I'm just in the very basic stages of this program so I'll start to clean it up, but I guess it's better to keep it tidy from the start. Thanks again for the advice.

Comment: Please provide details on your question. Do not provide external links.

Comment: StackOverflow has a built in image sharing space.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't realise. It highlights a part of my AppDelegate in green and says 'Thread 1: signal SIGABRT'. Also - what part of my question would you like more detail @flexaddicted?

Comment: @LouisHolley I mean you should upload the image in your question, if possible. In this way, other people can see the problem and suggest a fix. Thank you very much.

Comment: You got an exception. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961770/run-stop-on-objective-c-exception-in-xcode-4 for enabling exceptions in Xcode.

Comment: I don't have 10 rep and I need that to post an image unfortunately. If I enable the exception it still stops the program, it just changes the green message from 'signal SIGABRT' to 'exception breakpoint'

Comment: @LouisHolley Could you share the code you use to create the button? thanks

Comment: I used 

    `UIButton *Hard1;`

and

    `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *Hard1;`

in the interface file, then ctrl, clicked and dragged the Outlet to my button in the Interface Builder. Thanks for the response again.

Comment: In this case, using a xib, you don't need to add the button in  `viewDidLoad` method. It should works as is. Could you provide the crash log you see in the console? Please, edit your question with further details.

Comment: There is no crash log, the program carries out fine, the colour of the button simply remains unchanged

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `-setBackgroundImage:forState:` instead of `-setImage:forState:`

And also, as @flexaddicted said, you only want to add the button once.

Comment: Thanks for the response @iain, still having no effect on the button though

Answer (score 0):

If you are using button as switch you can like this way.

```
  _btnMale = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   [_btnMale setBackgroundImage:[ UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [_btnMale setBackgroundImage:[ UIImage imageNamed:@"checkMark.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
   _btnMale.tag = 1;
   _btnMale.frame = CGRectMake(150 , 9, 25, 25);
   [_btnMale addTarget:self action:@selector(selectGender:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [self addSubview:_btnMale];
```

Set button image for selected and normal state in viewDidLoad/viewDidAppear method as per your need. After declaration, in your target method add this code.

```
-(void)selectGender:(UIButton*)sender{

  sender.selected = ! sender.selected;

}
```

And then set other button to selected `NO`. then button will work like as a switch.

hope this will help you.