# How to get the correct frame of a rotated UIView (including correct position)

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have an app where I have a rectangle that the user can rotate and pan using their fingers. I'd simply like to know what the frame is of this rotated view so I can find out if it intersects another rectangular `UIView` (can't use the frame property because it gets invalidated when the UIView gets transformed). What's the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: can you post your transformation code...???

Comment: self.rotateAngle = rotateAngle;
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(self.rotateAngle);

Comment: try view.bounds it may help you.

Comment: are you doing this in animation block????

Comment: after the normal transformation i can get the frame using `frame` property....

Comment: @MountainLion it says in the docs that after a transformation the frame is invalidated, so would like to avoid using that anyway just in case changes in iOS, thanks for taking a look though.

Answer (score 0):

Every `UIView` has a property `frame` which is of type CGRect.

You can access it using `view.frame`.

After the transform is applied you can use the bounds and center property on the view to get the orientation. It may take a little bit of calculation but i hope you can get to it easily.

Refer to [this image](http://littlehales.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/coords.jpg) from an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361369/ios-programming-frame-bounds-and-center).

Comment: The frame property gets invalidated when there is a transformation.

Comment: Yes i am sorry i forgot about the transform.

Comment: Side note (just in case):  Please don't migrate spam (re: *Can a unlocked iphone use an pre-paid sim card with rogers?*).  Also, don't vote to migrate when you don't know the target site's faq.  Phone and phone service questions are off topic for [su].  Thanks.