# UIView after rotate change the coordinate

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, cgaffinetransform

When rotate the View

```
self.myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*40/100);
```

How i get the coordinate after the myView is rotate?

Is that possible view can change coordinate after rotate?

Comment: Is `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` the only transformation applied?

Comment: Your entire coordinate system changes as well when you use CGAffineTransform. So you can get coordinates. You just need to adjust them to the change the same way

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361369/uiview-frame-bounds-and-center