# iOS Animate Rotation at an Angle

Tags: ios, animation, rotation, transform, cabasicanimation

I'm trying to do a 360 spin of a view but at a 45 degree tilt.

Like this

[image]

I can't figure out for to do it.

So far I've managed this

```
CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation
                               animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.y"];
animation.fromValue = @(0);
animation.toValue = @(2 * M_PI);
animation.duration = 1;

[self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"rotation"];
```

Which spins it on it's y axis, but what I want is for this Y axis to be tilted 45 degree before it's spun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should see the link below which explains that the differences between "frame" and "bounds".
[UIView frame, bounds and center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361369/uiview-frame-bounds-and-center/11282765#11282765)

And now, here is my answer.

```
/* add the 4 lines below */
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_4);
self.layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 60.0f, 200.0f);
self.layer.position = CGPointMake(150.0f, 300.0f);

CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation
                               animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.y"];
animation.fromValue = @(0);
animation.toValue = @(2 * M_PI);
animation.duration = 1;

[self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"rotation"];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this;

```
CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation
                           animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];

CATransform3D rtfm = CATransform3DMakeRotation(2 * M_PI , 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
rtfm.m34 = -0.0015f;

animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DIdentity];
animation.toValue =   [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:rtfm];
animation.duration = 1;

[self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"rotation"];
```

Answer (score 0):

1- Change the anchor point to the upper right edge

```
self.someView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5);
```

2- rotate the view by 45 or 35 degrees

```
CGFloat radians = (M_PI/180) * (-35);
self.someView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.someView.transform, radians);
```

3- rotate or flip your view by X axis

```
CGFloat radians = (M_PI/180) * (180);
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        self.someView.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(self.someView.layer.transform,radians , 1, 0.0, 0.0);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if(finished) {
        }
    }];
```

Works like a charm :)