# UINavigationController - showing the UIToolbar and increasing its height

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar, cgrect

Based on what I have read on various posts on here, this should make my UIToolbar 200px taller than the default 44.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];
    CGRect toolbarFrame = self.navigationController.toolbar.frame;
    toolbarFrame.size.height += 200;
    toolbarFrame.origin.y -= 200;
    self.navigationController.toolbar.frame = toolbarFrame;
}
```

However, its rendering at the standard 44 when the view loads. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you moving the origin 200 points up?

Comment: I want the height to be 200 pts up , so I figured the origin needed to be higher

Comment: I would expect that increasing the height by 200 and decreasing the originY by 200 would result in a bar that is 244 points tall but has its bottom at the same location.

Comment: Exactly, otherwise increasing its height would move it off of the screen by 200px.

Comment: No, decreasing its origin by 200 points is what's moving it offscreen.

Comment: Maybe this will help you understand. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361369/uiview-frame-bounds-and-center

Comment: Ok ,but even if I make it 500 bigger, it doesn't change the appearance. Nothing seems to have an effect.

Comment: And I've always thought the parent frame's origin is 0,0 - so decreasing the y factor moves it up the screen, not down.

Comment: I was making the (probably incorrect) assumption that your toolbar was at the top.

Comment: sorry, no. The UINavigationController has a toolbar view (not visible by default) that shows up on the bottom of the view.

Answer (score 0):

The docs say that you can't directly modify UIToolbar attached to the UINavigationController.

I ended up creating a new one and adding it to the subview.