# self.view.frame.size change values at the same orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, orientation

Some very strange issue for me:

```
- (void)horizontalPickerView:(HorizontalPickerView *)picker didSelectElementAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
        self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        sdashSize = CGRectMake(0.0f, 40.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    } else {
        sdashSize = CGRectMake(0.0f, 40.0f, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width - 40.0f);
    }
}
```

Like you see, I have a picker view. This method runs every time, that I select something in this picker view. So now if I rotate my iPhone into Landscape and go to the next view with this code, it runs once -> goes to if state and gives me size: 320 x 480. So now select some element at the same orientation and runs the same code (if state once again) gives me 480 x 320. I do not understand how could the same code at the same orientation could give me the different values.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the `frame` property, use the `bounds` property. In essence:

- A view's **frame** (CGRect) is the position of its rectangle in the superview's coordinate system. By default it starts at the top left.
- A view's **bounds** (CGRect) expresses a view rectangle in its own coordinate system.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11282765/1027644) explains further in depth what is going on.