# UIView Frame and Bounds

Tags: uiview, scrollview, frame, bounds

Im relatively new to iOs and working in UIViews frame and bounds...

When I worked on UIScrollview and trying to get a handle on ZoomToRect, minimumZoomScale and ZoomScale etc... I was logging the bounds and frame after zooming and the Frame was smaller than the bounds of the UIImageView? 
I thought that the frame and the bounds are supposed to be relative?

How can the frame be smaller?

I can figure that the bounds is the viewing window but maybe I do not fully understand the relationship between those two properties...

Comment: Please go through [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11282765/2954866). See if it answers your question.

Comment: Mostly... but it makes sense that the frame can be larger than bounds especially when a view is rotated. But in the case of the ImageView inside of a scrollView... In that case when the ImageView is zoomed the frame is smaller than the bounds... But that might be because the bounds are actually viewable and the frame is being set relative to the ScollViews bounds...?