# iOS: understanding frame and views

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiimageview

I am working programmatically an application for iOS based on a ViewController. I am trying to do so programmatically as I want to understand the underlying concepts.

I have created a subclass of UIImageView and initialized this using an image. In the initialization method I added also a second UIImageView as I would like to handle the two differently but be part of the same object. Ultimately I would like to be able to scale the object (and hence the 2 UIImages) according to the device screen resolution (e.g. if resolution is low then I will scale the two images by 50%). I want to do this because I would like to be able to implement a zoom in and zoom out feature as well as **supporting multiple resolutions and screen layouts**.

Additional information:

- The two images have different size (500x500 pixels) and (350x350
  pixels).

My questions are:

- **how do I position the second image exactly in the center of the first?** (I used the center property of the main UIImage but I think I got it wrong.. I thought that the center was the exact center of the square but either I am using it incorrectly or there is something I am missing)
- **are there any negative side effects for using this approach (UIView subclass class containing an additional UIView?)** (E.g. Is it going to create confusion when applying transformation algorithms? Does it reduce the randering speed? Or more simply is it a bad design pattern?)

[image: here is a little example of how it should look like..]

I find it difficult to understand the positioning of the second image. See code snipped below, this is what I use:

```
    CGRect innerButtonFrame = CGRectMake(self.center.x/2, self.center.y/2,innerButtonSelectedImage.size.width,innerButtonSelectedImage.size.height);
```

Taken from:

```
-(id) initWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    if(self = [super initWithImage:image]){
        //
        self.userInteractionEnabled = true;

        // Initialize gesture recognizers
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapInView = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapInImageView:)];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:tapInView];

        UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressInView:)];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:longPress];


        // Initialize labels
        ..

        // Inner circle image
        innerButtonView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        innerButtonSelectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"inner circle.png"];

        CGRect innerButtonFrame = CGRectMake(self.center.x/2, self.center.y/2,innerButtonSelectedImage.size.width,innerButtonSelectedImage.size.height);

        innerButtonView.frame = innerButtonFrame;
        [innerButtonView setImage:innerButtonSelectedImage];

        // Add additional ui components to view
        [self addSubview:innerButtonView];
        .. 
        [self addSubview:descriptionLabel];
    }
    return self;
}
```

**EDIT: This is how it looks like if I change the positioning code to the following:**

```
CGRect innerButtonFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0,innerButtonSelectedImage.size.width,innerButtonSelectedImage.size.height);

        innerButtonView.frame = innerButtonFrame;
```

I also don't understand why the image is bigger than the screen.. as the blue one should be 500x500 pixel wide and the screen of the iPhone 6 should be 1334 x 750.

[image]

Comment: Understand the differences between frame, bounds and center. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361369/uiview-frame-bounds-and-center

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
CGRect innerButtonFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, innerButtonSelectedImage.size.width,innerButtonSelectedImage.size.height);
innerButtonFrame.center = self.center;
```

Comment: Thanks but there is no center property in the CGRect data structure.

Comment: PS: I added an edit using a modified version of the code you suggested. Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `innerButtonView.frame = innerButtonFrame; innerButtonView.center = self.center;`

Answer (score 0):

If you need 500*500 circle then add the circle half means Replace **500*500** with **250*250** . And small circle replace **350*350** with **175*175** And solve your problem.

I hope your problem will solve..Enjoy

Thanks..