# iOS - positions on iPhone 4 / 5 / 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have problems with positioning floating buttons in right location based on the screen size. It works great when on iPhone 4s but it's in completely different place when on iPhone 6. 
Could you tell me how to determinate the different iPhones please?

iPhone 4s

```
editOptionsView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(226.0f, 540.0f, [[self view] bounds].size.height, 40.0f)];
```

iPhone 6

```
editOptionsView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(226.0f, 627.0f, [[self view] bounds].size.height, 40.0f)];
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: You should use Auto Layout, it is intended to solve many problems, this being one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The 'bounds' property of the view should give you what you're looking for.

[UIView frame, bounds and center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361369/uiview-frame-bounds-and-center)

Answer (score 0):

You can always get the screen size by asking the main screen:

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]
```

although it's not always the best practice.