# What is the relationship between a UIView's frame origin and its center?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, cgrect

Say I'm creating an animation, and I want to move the center of a UIView to a certain `CGPoint` I have. I know what I want the center to be, just the aforementioned `CGPoint`, and I know the width and height that I want, but when I go to create the frame for my `UIView` I have no idea what to set for the `x` and `y` for the `origin`.

Should I just be setting `0, 0` or anything really? Does it matter?

Should I just be thinking as setting `center` as a different method of setting the origin? Makes me wish CGRect had an instantiator with `center` as an option.

There has been a previous question addressing a somewhat similar question, but it addresses them as three separate entities, rather than how to deal with center when creating the view.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIView frame, bounds and center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361369/uiview-frame-bounds-and-center)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, go ahead and set the initial frame's origin to anything, since subsequently setting the center will effectively move this origin anyway. It is not uncommon to initialise views with a frame of `CGRectZero` when it is going to be fully configured later.

`frame` is actually just a calculated property based on the view's `center` and `bounds`, and so all three are intrinsically linked when it comes to view layout. The [UIView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/center) has this to say about it:

> The geometry of a view is defined by its `frame`, `bounds`, and `center`
>   properties. The `frame` defines the origin and dimensions of the view in
>   the coordinate system of its superview and is commonly used during
>   layout to adjust the size or position of the view. The `center` property
>   can be used to adjust the position of the view without changing its
>   size. The bounds defines the internal dimensions of the view as it
>   sees them and is used almost exclusively in custom drawing code. The
>   size portion of the `frame` and bounds rectangles are coupled together
>   so that changing the size of either rectangle updates the size of
>   both.