# How to center any subview horizontally in parent UIView but not vertically?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to center any subview in its parent UIview only horizontally, not vertically. I tried `child.center = parent.center` but it place my child view in the center of the parent view both horizontally and vertically. How can i align it in  center just horizontally. Thanks

Comment: Set only center.x and ignore y value

Comment: center is a CGPoint.  yous should just be able to set the x value of it to the parent views center x value

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Changing only the center like this may help

```
child.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(parentView.bounds), child.center.y);
```

Comment: Will you please tell me that is there any difference between  child.center.y  and child.origin.y.

Comment: @ChrisH Yeah I made a mistake in the answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Zeebok center tells the center point of view in it's superview's coordinate system whereas origin tells location of view in it's superview coordinate system. For detailed description check this [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361369/uiview-frame-bounds-and-center) question.

Comment: @Jaideep np - you could also take this one step further and use `parent.center.x` as the first value.

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify the `x` property of the `UIViewController`'s `center` directly, but you can do the following:

```
CGPoint center = child.center;
center.x = parent.center.x;
child.center = center;
```

Comment: Many Thanks Jaideep, your answer is superb. Your Answer is much easy to understand, but i am little bit confused. Jaideep also gave a good answer, i am confused which one should i accept. Your both are fabulous.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
subview.frame = CGRectMake(((parentView.frame.size.width/2)-(subview.frame.size.width/2)),subview.frame.origin.y,subview.frame.size.width,subview.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to horizontally centre (but not vertically) a UIImageView for each different device size, so I used this, which worked well:

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
[self.myImageView setCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(screenRect), self.myImageView.frame.origin.y + self.myImageView.frame.size.height/2)];
```