# iAd on top of view in landscape

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

Right now I have an iAd banner on the bottom of my view when the device is in landscape. How do I get the iAd banner to be on top of the view when the device is in landscape?

```
banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, -banner.frame.size.width/50, -banner.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Banner.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,480,32);
```

is the solution

Answer (score 0):

You should not be setting static points for your `ADBannerView`. What happens when you run your application on a device that has different screen dimensions?

What you should be doing is setting your `ADBannerView`'s `frame` relative to the `UIView` it is displayed within, like so:

```
iAdBannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, iAdBannerView.frame.size.height);
```

Read the answers to this question, [UIView frame, bounds and center](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5361369/2108547), for a better understanding of what `frame` refers to exactly.