# How to change the height of webView dynamically using Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, webview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am working on a iOS app using Xamarin iOS and I have a webView that loads local html, However the webView takes up the entire screen so there is no place to put a back button.

here's my load localhtml code:

```
using CoreGraphics;
using Foundation;
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.IO;
using UIKit;

namespace AppName
{
    partial class View : UIViewController{


        public View(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            var webView = new UIWebView(new CGRect(0, 20, View.Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height -20));
            View.AddSubview(webView);



            // Method 2 using LoadRequest
            string fileName = "Content/local.html"; // remember case-sensitive
            string localHtmlUrl = Path.Combine(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, fileName);
            webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(localHtmlUrl, false)));
            webView.ScalesPageToFit = false;
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }
    }
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
var webView = new UIWebView(new CGRect(0, 20, View.Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height -20));
```

You're setting the frame of the web view to the full frame of your controller's frame (except for the y position, which you're setting to 20 px from top).

I think you should read [UIView frame, bounds and center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361369/uiview-frame-bounds-and-center).

Comment: How to do the same for `WKWebView`