# Fix animation of pop-up scroll menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, xcode6

I'm trying to make a menu that slides up from the button via the activation of a UIbutton. When you press the button, a UIscrollView slides up from the bottom. The button also stays above the slide menu when the UIbutton is and isn't activated. 
Here's what it should look like:
[image]

I have the screen locked to portrait mode in my actual project, the issue is that when you press the button. The UIscrollView slides to the middle of the screen and when you press the button again, it only moves down a few. And the button doesn't move **WITH** the UIscrollView. I want to make it so the UI scrollView and Unbutton comes up like in the picture above and goes down **UNDER** the screen viewport. 
This is what my actual project looks like - http://s4.postimg.org/dlvxnffbx/unnamed.png

Here are the code from the viewcontroller.m for the animations.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()


@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize scrollView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    draw1 = 0;
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, 480, 55);
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(480, 55)];

    openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(220, 270, 60, 30);
}
- (IBAction)OpenMenu:(id)sender {
    if (draw1 ==0) {
        draw1 = 1;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

        [UIButton beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIButton setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIButton setAnimationDelay:0.0];
        [UIButton setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

        scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 245, 568, 55);
        openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(220, 200, 60, 30);

        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:scrollView];

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    } else {
        draw1 = 0;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

        [UIButton beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIButton setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIButton setAnimationDelay:0.0];
        [UIButton setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

        scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, 568, 55);
        openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(220, 270, 60, 30);

        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:scrollView];

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to replace:

```
if (draw1 ==0) {
    draw1 = 1;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

    [UIButton beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIButton setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIButton setAnimationDelay:0.0];
    [UIButton setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 245, 568, 55);
    openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(220, 200, 60, 30);

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:scrollView];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
} else {
    draw1 = 0;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

    [UIButton beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIButton setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIButton setAnimationDelay:0.0];
    [UIButton setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, 568, 55);
    openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(220, 200, 60, 30);

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:scrollView];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

with :

```
    if (draw1 ==0) {
        draw1 = 1;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                             scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 1000, 568, 55);
                             openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(220, 200, 60, 30);
                         } 
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             NSLog(@"Done!");
                         }];
    } else {
        draw1 = 0;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                             scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, 568, 55);
                             openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(220, 270, 60, 30);
                         } 
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             NSLog(@"Done!");
                         }];
    }
```

Comment: I get the error: "Implicit conversation from enumeration type enum UIViewAnimationCurve' to different enumeration type 'UIViewAnimationOptions' (aka ' enum UIViewAnimationOptions'0 on this line of code:    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut

Comment: sorry, try with UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut. Edited my answer

Comment: i just tried it, the UIscrollView comes to the center of the screen (and looks like this - http://s4.postimg.org/dlvxnffbx/unnamed.png) but never closes.

Comment: Edited my answer. try it and what happen?

Comment: Wait, I'm confused about the scrollview.frame stuff, can you edit it into my code?

Comment: I edited your codes. And I suggested you have to check the frames. Pls check them carefully.

Comment: See 2 last line in my answer. Maybe your frames are incorrect.

Comment: where do I put this: scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 568, 55);
    openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(220, 10, 60, 30);

Comment: replace scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 245, 568, 55);
    openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(220, 200, 60, 30);. as i mention

Comment: The only thing that happens is that the UIscrollView goes all the way to the top of the screen and when i press the button again, nothing happens.

Comment: Good, it means animation works fine. I edited my answer again

Comment: Let try it. Edited. And what happen?

Comment: It's working almost perfectly. The UIscrollView goes up then when i press the button again, it goes back under the viewport. Now how do i make the scrollview taller in height, let's say 200 or something.

Comment: Set it what you want. Just change frames (e.g. CGRectMake(0, 300, 568, 55)) values, and see what happen. And choose what you want.

Comment: Please mark my answer is correct. So someone can read it when needed.

Comment: Can you give me an example and thank you for your help :)

Comment: E.g. this line is for scroll scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, 568, 55); change 300->200. or100  ==> scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, 568, 55); or scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 568, 55); or any value. And the same for others .frame=CGRectMake

Comment: You should read more about frame of UIView. Like:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361369/uiview-frame-bounds-and-center

Comment: CGRectMake(x, y, width, height) - is that correct syntax for CGRectMake?

Answer (score 1):

If  you are looking it should slide from button, means at start its frame size should be zero and start emerging from button center and should get full size then you should set frame before animation  like this

Below code will bring scrollView from bottom of screen when you want to open and on close it will hide scrollView bottom of the screen...

In viewDidLoad method set initial frame what ever you want... if you want it to hide then set y position of scrollView greater then height of superView, in that case It will hide view at bottom.

```
(draw) {
    // to open
    draw = 0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 55, self.view.bounds.size.width, 55);
        openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(220, scrollView.frame.origin.y - 40, 60, 30);

    }];
}
else
{
    //close
    draw = 1;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height + 55, self.view.bounds.size.width, 55);
        openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(220, scrollView.frame.origin.y - 40, 60, 30);

    }];
}
```

Comment: I'm still a bit confused, can you edit it into my code?

Comment: Can you give me ur start and end view (what you want), I will write code for that

Comment: I think it's in the code that I included in my question, not sure what you are asking. (i'm new to objective-c)