# Unable to center a custom uibutton within a uiview dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiview

Here is what I am doing. I have a `UITableViewCell` within a row of UITableView.

I have now created a UIView and added it as subview to UITableViewCell.Within the UIView I have created a  custom button and wanted to be in the center of the UIView but when I center it the button goes down out of the UIView.

I gave background colors for the images attached for better understanding.

Grey: custom UIButton 
Red: UIView
Green: UITableViewCell
Blue: Lable which is over Green

Before centering button:
[image]

After center button:

[image]

Here is the code for the same after centering:

```
tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath: 

NSString *cellidentifier=@"cell";
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];
if(cell==nil){
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
}

cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

//adding deviceName label
SFIDevice *device=(SFIDevice *)[self.deviceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Heavy" size:14];
UILabel *deviceNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, 25)];
deviceNameLabel.text = device.deviceName;
deviceNameLabel.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
deviceNameLabel.font=font;
deviceNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[cell addSubview:deviceNameLabel];

SensorIndexSupport *Index=[[SensorIndexSupport alloc]init];
NSArray *deviceIndexes=[Index getIndexesFor:device.deviceType];

UIView *cellView = [self addMyButton:cell withYScale:25  withDeviceIndex:deviceIndexes];
cellView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

return cell;
```

calling add my button:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cellFrame.frame.origin.x,
                                                              yScale,
                                                              self.view.frame.size.width,
                                                              frameSize)];
[cellFrame addSubview:view];
int i=0;
for (SFIDeviceIndex *deviceIndex in deviceIndexes) {
    for (IndexValueSupport *iVal in deviceIndex.indexValues) {
        i++;

        SFIRulesSwitchButton *btnBinarySwitchOn = [[SFIRulesSwitchButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, frameSize, frameSize)];
        SFIDimmerButton *dimbtn=[[SFIDimmerButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x,view.frame.origin.y, dimFrameWidth, dimFrameHeight)];
        btnBinarySwitchOn.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

        btnBinarySwitchOn.selected = NO;
        [btnBinarySwitchOn addTarget:btnBinarySwitchOn action:@selector(onButtonClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [btnBinarySwitchOn setupValues:[UIImage imageNamed:iVal.iconName] Title:iVal.displayText];

        btnBinarySwitchOn.frame = CGRectMake(btnBinarySwitchOn.frame.origin.x + ((i-1) * (frameSize/2))+textHeight/2 ,
                                             btnBinarySwitchOn.frame.origin.y,
                                             btnBinarySwitchOn.frame.size.width,
                                             btnBinarySwitchOn.frame.size.height);

        btnBinarySwitchOn.center = view.center;
        [view addSubview:btnBinarySwitchOn];

    }

}
return view;
```

code for centering the button:

```
btnBinarySwitchOn.center = view.center;
```

Comment: I think it is because of the frame you set for the btnBinarySwitchOn.

Comment: @PK20 commented it out and checked. Still the same

Comment: If that is not the reason, then check for your UIView frame.

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361369/uiview-frame-bounds-and-center?rq=1) has more info on UIView frame, bunds and center

Comment: @PK20 I changed the xy co-ordinates of UIView to (0,0) and the button is alinging well in center, but I want something like (0, 25), and this makes button to go out of UIView

Comment: try like `child.center = [parent convertPoint:parent.center fromView:parent.superview];`

Comment: or like `child.center = CGPointMake(parent.bounds.height/2, parent.bounds.width/2)` either one should help

Comment: Also see if it allows you to code like `btnBinarySwitchOn.center = view.view.center;` These are few options that you can try out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is this line `btnBinarySwitchOn.center = view.center;`

Maybe this is what you want:

```
btnBinarySwitchOn.center = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width/2,
                                       view.frame.size.height/2);
```

Comment: You should use the `bounds` and `not` the `frame`, as the frame is undefined if the view has a `transform`.

Comment: @anhtu: thanks! it worked, can you explain what could have happened.

Comment: @PK20: sure, I will have a look at bounds. Yes, when I rotated the screen, the view did not stretch, neither with bounds or frame

Comment: @Masood  the value of `view.center` is the value of **view's center in view's superview**. It's not the **center of the view**.

Comment: @Masood try to log `view.center` and `CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width/2,
                                       view.frame.size.height/2)` to see what happen. :)