# Best choice when detecting whether a view's point is inside another view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, cgrect, cgpoint

So I've found 3 ways to make this happen.

1. `convertPoint:toView:`
   `convertPoint:fromView:`
   `convertRect:toView:`
   `convertRect:fromView:`
2. `Bool CGRectContainsPoint(CGRect rect, CGPoint point);`
3. `BOOL isPointInsideView = [aView pointInside:aPoint withEvent:nil];`

They all seem to do the same but I might be wrong. You check if a point is inside a certain view considering its frame then get either true or false.

Does it not matter which one of them I end up using or should I be aware of issues that might arise..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should be aware of what each method is used for:**

The docs for [`pointInside:withEvent:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/pointInside:withEvent:) say

> `point` | A point that is in the receiver’s local coordinate system (`bounds`).

Apart from that the method probably does simply call `CGRectContainsPoint` with the passed point and the bounds frame.

`CGRectContainsPoint` simply does the math of checking the `x` and `y` coordinates against the `origin` and `size`. Simple math, but once again both have to be in the same coordinate system since neither the rect nor the point contain any information about their respective coordinate system, they are absolute values.

The `convert*` functions offer you the ability to transform the CGPoint which is relative to the receiver's coordinate system into some other relative coordinate system.

To understand what each method is good for, you have to understand what the different `CGRect`s mean, `frame` and `bounds` in particular: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11282765/2442804) is THE way to go for that.

After understanding what the different properties mean it should be easy to pick the correct function.

TL;DR: the `convert*` methods offer you the ability to transform `CGPoint`s between coordinate systems. The other two options operate within one certain fixed coordinate system. It is your job to pick the one you need in your particular case.

For example you might have to transform a point first and then perform the hit detection.

Comment: Ok for example, By using panGesture I'm sliding a view over another view and not when they intersect but when the sliding view's center point intersects with the other view's bounds, I want to trigger delegates/methods. In this scenario.. which one would you pick?

Comment: @durazno I would say you get the center of your sliding view, transform it via `convertPoint:toView:` and then call `pointInside`. The first you call on the sliding view, the second one on the one you want to check for intersection

Comment: Why can't I just call CGRectContainsPoint? Wouldn't that get the sliding view's center point then check if the other view contains the point?

Comment: @durazno it *might* work. But the problem is that the center point of slidingView is not guaranteed to be in the same coordinate space as the one of `toCheckForView`. One more tricky point: the `center` property is in the superViews coordinate space, so you would have to call `convertPoint:toView:` on the superview of `slidingView`. If `slidingView` and `toCheckForView` are in the same exact superview, then CGRectContainsPoint could work.