# When scrolling a tableview I need the row that's passing at the very top of the tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a table view, I need the indexpath of the row that is passing at the very top (0,0) of the tableview, I try to use the indexPathForRow(at:) which is expecting a cgpoint, I try CGPoint.zero to get the row, but the indexPath is always nil, I read that I need to play with offset of the scrollView and that point need to be in the local coordinate but so far no luck

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let cgPoint = CGPoint.zero
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: cgPoint)
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

There could be only one reason why this gonna be nil because of your point not bound in tablview bounds.

Apple Documentation:

> An index path representing the row and section associated with point, or nil if the point is out of the bounds of any row.
>   point in the local coordinate system of the table view (the table view’s bounds).

Try this.

```
let cgPoint = CGPoint.zero

if self.tableView.frame.contains(cgPoint) {
     print("point exist so indexpath should exist")
}
```

Ref: [Diff between bounds and frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361369/uiview-frame-bounds-and-center)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert (0,0) into the **table view's bounds coordinate** first, like this:

```swift
// Take (0,0) from parent view, find where it locates in table view's bounds
let p = tableView.superview!.convert(.zero, to: tableView)
guard let ind = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: p) else { return }
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: ind)! // Do what you want
```

[Demo gif](https://gph.is/2R82pbw)