# UIProgressView displaying issues in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uiprogressview

I need UIProgressView as part of UITableView cell for one iOS 7 application. I have added UIProgressView from code on the right side of cell like this:

```
_progressBar = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleDefault];
_progressBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.contentView addSubview:_progressBar];

[self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_progressBar attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_progressBar attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0 constant:-10.0]];
[_progressBar addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_progressBar attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:60.0]];
[_progressBar addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_progressBar attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:12.0]];
```

However, displaying UIProgressView is a bit strange. When progress is zero, UIProgressView object looks like this:

[image]

When I set progress value to 0.5, UIProgressView becomes rectangle on the left and remains rounded rectangle on the right:

[image]

And when I set progress to 0.98, looks like this:

[image]

Any idea how to fill UIProgressView by simply setting progress value and that rounded rectangle (or rectangle) form of element are kept the entire time? Or is this impossible without adding custom graphics or overriding UIProgressView?

Many thanks in advance and best regards.

Comment: I think the height of an UIProgressView is fixed.

Comment: the height of progressview can be change, and it would be better to do it using CGAffineTransform

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Had the same problem today and fix is not that hard :)

In interface builder add a UIView with the exact same size as the UIProgressView. Add your UIProgressView in this new UIView.

Do the following for your UIView if you want corners:

1) Set cornerradius to the half of the height (e.g. 30px height progressbar means 15px corner radius UIVIew))

```
myView.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
```

2) Set mask to bounds

```
myView.layer.masksToBounds = TRUE;
```

3) Set clip to bounds so nothing can come out of the UIView

```
myView.clipsToBounds = TRUE;
```

And now you have a rounded UIProgressBar with the height you want.

If you don't want rounded corners just add a UIView as the same way but only change the background color to the same grey as the UIProgressbar tracktint.

Goodluck!

-Sjoerd

Comment: even easier: change the background of the `UIView` to `clearColor`

Comment: aren't `clipsToBounds` and `masksToBounds` the same? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177775/how-is-the-relation-between-uiviews-clipstobounds-and-calayers-maskstobounds

Answer (score 5):

For future reference: I've solved this issue by setting the corner radius like

```
  _progressView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0;
```

And then:

```
  _progressView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

No need for a container for the UIProgressView.